# How should I create a Login in a HTML5 mobile app?

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, mobile, jsonp

I've developing a HTML5 mobile app, and i'm targeting mainly Android and iOS.

I was searching about JSONP with JQuery AJAX, to pass the information from the mobile device to the server-side, but I wanted to know your opinion about this, I'm not aware of the security issues in this approach...

Should I continue with JSONP and AJAX? Or should change to another method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just looked around a bit and found this post [Is it safe to use ajax for login?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938969/is-it-safe-to-use-ajax-for-login), this might help a bit with regards to security, just make sure that you always validate any input from any form.

Personally I don't think that AJAX or JSONP is a problem.