# How to decrypt a string with OpenSSL which was previously encrypted with mcrypt?

Tags: php, mcrypt, php-openssl

Since mcrypt was deprecated in PHP 7.1 and I have a lot of data encrypted/decrypted with mcrypt in existing project, how to migrate my PHP code from mcrypt to OpenSSL? I have the following code to encrypt:

```
$encoded = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, 'salt', 'source string', MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
```

And decryption code is:

```
$source = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, 'salt', base64_decode('encoded string'), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
```

What `openssl_` functions should I use in the above examples to get the same results without encoded data conversion?

Or the only way is to run a script which will decrypt all my stored encrypted data with mcrypt and encode with openssl?

Thanks

Comment: Do not use ECB mode, it is not secure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

Comment: [PHP replace mcrypt with openssl](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9993909/608639)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OpenSSL doesn't have the Rijndael-256 cipher; there's no equivalent - you'll have to decrypt and re-encrypt everything.

But also:

- You're missing padding and authentication.
- Don't use ECB mode.
- "salt" is not a proper encryption key, nor is any regular string. Use [random_bytes()](https://secure.php.net/random_bytes) to generate your keys, *with the proper key length for the chosen algorithm*.

All of the above can be summed up like this: **don't do it on your own, use a well-vetted library** like [defuse/php-encryption](https://packagist.org/packages/defuse/php-encryption).

Cryptography is no simple thing and you can't do it properly with just 5 lines of code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you suggest an appropriate random_bytes() length? Could you advise an openssl algorythm similar to or better than Rijndael-256 for regular website use such as passwords encryption? My actual task is not a user password encryption, but similar.

Comment: There's no universally good length ... it depends on the algorithm. As for the algorithm itself, again - just use a library.