# Moving from mcrypt with Blowfish & ECB to OpenSSL

Tags: php, openssl, mcrypt, blowfish

In the (not too distant) past a decision has been made (by someone who longer works here) to always 'encrypt' database IDs to something else, on the fly, whenever it was needed for external communication.

Now, we've moved from PHP 5.x to PHP 7.0 for our main application, and our microservices scattered across our infrastructure are running either 7.0 or 7.1. The 7.1 servers keep throwing deprecation warnings for the mcrypt stuff. No biggie, just yet. But with PHP 7.2 around the corner, we want to keep updating and upgrading. Mcrypt is blocking.

To save all the currently encrypted values in 60 tables, across 1400 databases, is a huge task. Is there a way to leverage OpenSSL, with Blowfish and ECB, to get the same encoded and decoded values to lull us into a false sense of security? All so we can plan our database migrations far ahead.

Basically, the currently encrypted value is this:

`item:13fb7533bf19399ff114468b194ebfaf`

This is ID `123`. It goes through the following functions to get to this string:

```
$id   = 123;
$type = 'item';

$serialized = serialize('' . $id); // To make sure always a string gets put in

$ivSize = mcrypt_create_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);
$iv     = mcrypt_create_iv($ivSize);

$passCrypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $type, $serialized, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
$encoded   = bin2hex($passCrypt); // `13fb7533bf19399ff114468b194ebfaf`

$encryptedId = $type . ':' . $encoded;
```

This gives the final result `item:13fb7533bf19399ff114468b194ebfaf`.

Now, for the other way around:

```
$encryptedId = 'item:13fb7533bf19399ff114468b194ebfaf';

$type = 'item';
$encryptedIdOnly = substr($encryptedId, strlen($type) + 1); // `13fb...`

$decoded   = hex2bin($encryptedIdOnly);
$iv        = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND);
$decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, 'item', $decoded, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv); // This gives ' `s:3:"123";` '

$unserialized = unserialize($decrypted); // '123'
```

I've tried it for several hours, but I'm completely blindsided by anything crypto (but I want to learn!). My current code is:

```
$cipher = 'BF-ECB';
//$cipher = 'BF'; (I've tried both, no difference)

$isCtypeXDigit = ctype_xdigit($decipher);
$decoded       = hex2bin($decipher);
$ivLength      = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
$randomBytes   = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivLength);
$decrypted     = openssl_decrypt($decoded, $cipher, $prefix, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_NO_PADDING, $randomBytes);
$unserialized  = unserialize($decrypted);
```

Which gives me a thousand things, all similiar to `��IY_Lc�d:�_���`. Could anyone shine any light on this -- is it even possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is very tricky. You can just use the code.

```
# cat a.php
<?php
function mcrypt_blowfish_encrypt_hex($key, $str)
{
    $encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $key, $str, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    return bin2hex($encrypted);
}

function make_openssl_blowfish_key($key)
{
    if("$key" === '')
        return $key;

    $len = (16+2) * 4;
    while(strlen($key) < $len) {
        $key .= $key;
    }
    $key = substr($key, 0, $len);
    return $key;
}

function openssl_blowfish_encrypt_hex($key, $str)
{
    $blockSize = 8;
    $len = strlen($str);
    $paddingLen = intval(($len + $blockSize - 1) / $blockSize) * $blockSize - $len;
    $padding = str_repeat("\0", $paddingLen);
    $data = $str . $padding;
    $key = make_openssl_blowfish_key($key);
    $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data, 'BF-ECB', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING);
    return bin2hex($encrypted);
}

function openssl_blowfish_decrypt_hex($key, $hex)
{
    $key = make_openssl_blowfish_key($key);
    $decrypted = openssl_decrypt(hex2bin($hex), 'BF-ECB', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING);
    return rtrim($decrypted, "\0");
}


function test()
{
    for($i = 1; $i < 32; $i++) {
        for($j = 1; $j < 32; $j++) {
            $key = str_repeat('' . rand(0, 9), $j);
            $str = str_repeat('' . rand(0, 9), $i);

            $encoded_openssl = openssl_blowfish_encrypt_hex($key, $str);
            $decoded_openssl = openssl_blowfish_decrypt_hex($key, $encoded_openssl);
            if($decoded_openssl != $str)
                die("encrypt($key, $str) wrong: $encoded_openssl: decrypt failed\n");


            if(function_exists('mcrypt_encrypt')) {
                $encoded_mcrypt = mcrypt_blowfish_encrypt_hex($key, $str);
                if($encoded_openssl != $encoded_mcrypt)
                    die("encrypt($key, $str) wrong: $encoded_openssl, mcrypt=$encoded_mcrypt\n");
            }

            echo "key='$key', str='$str', encrypted='$encoded_openssl'\n";
        }
    }
}

echo "openssl: thisismyitemyes:" . openssl_blowfish_encrypt_hex('thisismyitemyes', serialize('6918')) . "\n";
echo "openssl: headphone:" . openssl_blowfish_encrypt_hex('headphone', serialize('581856')) . "\n";

test();
```

And run, it works:

```
# php a.php
openssl: thisismyitemyes:b192ac0f6105416a710aec3ce92b1085
openssl: headphone:ef057c036eb024865406838c62590a93
key='7', str='3', encrypted='945b638624ecbd5e'
key='22', str='1', encrypted='3daf096bdc744d8a'
key='888', str='0', encrypted='b164bb0b603f439e'
key='2222', str='9', encrypted='d3458df30aef0b4b'
...
...
key='3333333333333333333333333333333', str='11111111111111111111111111111', encrypted='b0c9bf45d6f5c7b3b0c9bf45d6f5c7b3b0c9bf45d6f5c7b363a25777c712f1d5'
key='4444444444444444444444444444444', str='999999999999999999999999999999', encrypted='dd6aaf466121c0f6dd6aaf466121c0f6dd6aaf466121c0f659a2271369ab6731'
key='7777777777777777777777777777777', str='3333333333333333333333333333333', encrypted='6591e9cc92a6473a6591e9cc92a6473a6591e9cc92a6473a208a7a562babc60c'
```

The problems:

1. IVs are ignored in ECB mode, so just remove all IVs in your code.
2. Due to bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72362 . In `mcrypt`, the blowfish key is cycled over by the short key. But in `openssl`, the blowfish key is zero-padded by the short key. So we need to make a cycled key for openssl to decrypt the mcrypt's encryption.
3. When you are using zero-padding with openssl (keep the same output of mcrypt), you should do the padding by yourself. Well, I did a trick to get the paddingLen, but it is really easy: just think about how many bytes we should append to make the total length is 0/8/16/24/32/40, etc.

Comment: @shawn I think you should trim only `\0` in `openssl_blowfish_decrypt_hex` to not remove spaces and 0s. I think last line should look like `return trim($decrypted, "\0");`