# Migrating mcrypt with Blowfish and ECB to OpenSSL

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, mcrypt

I can't for the life of me figure out how to migrate my legacy mcrypt code to OpenSSL. I got it working for Blowfish with CBC and for Rijndael with CBC, but Blowfish with ECB is eluding me.

And yes, I read [Moving from mcrypt with Blowfish & ECB to OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49171425/moving-from-mcrypt-with-blowfish-ecb-to-openssl) and I tried zero-padding the data, not zero-padding the data, zero-padding the key, cycling over the key and any combination of them and nothing seems to work.

This is my code:

```
<?php
function encrypt_with_mcrypt($data, $key) {
        return mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
}

function encrypt_with_openssl($data, $key) {
        return openssl_encrypt($data, 'BF-ECB', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_DONT_ZERO_PAD_KEY);
}

$data = 'foobar';
$key = 'supersecretkey';

var_dump(base64_encode(encrypt_with_mcrypt($data, $key)));
var_dump(base64_encode(encrypt_with_openssl($data, $key)));
```

And this is the output:

```
test.php:13:
string(12) "5z0q3xNnokw="
test.php:14:
string(12) "1zyqavq7sCk="
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mcrypt library / wrapper defaults to zero-byte padding (only when required) while OpenSSL library / wrapper defaults to PKCS#5 padding. That means that the single block gets padded differently and will therefore show a different block of ciphertext.

---

A common trick is to decrypt the resulting ciphertext *without* any unpadding and then check the padding bytes by viewing the plaintext + padding in hexadecimals.

This will show you:

```
5z0q3xNnokw=
666f6f6261720000
```

for mcrypt and

```
1zyqavq7sCk=
666f6f6261720202
```

for OpenSSL.

Using a larger plaintext message that requires multiple blocks to be encrypted would also have shown you that encryption is going fine *except* for the last block.

---

First zero-pad your data *if and only if* the mcrypt input is not a multiple of 8 bytes (the block size of Blowfish), then use `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` as the padding mode.

Note that looking at the source code shows that `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` for some unspecified reason seems to mean "no padding" for the wrapper and `OPENSSL_NO_PADDING` does seem to conflict with other settings - this I regard as a rather bad design and implementation mistake by the developers of the PHP OpenSSL wrapper API.

More info can be found by [the great research performed by Reinier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52544212/589259) that shows how the API pads / unpads (or forgets to pad / unpad, depending on where you stand).

Comment: Learn a man how to fish and your kajak keeps getting trapped in fishing lines and the man will shout abuse at you :P

Comment: "Using OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING may cause trouble as OpenSSL always pads": I believe this is incorrect. The PHP glue layer to OpenSSL explicitly disables padding in that case [here](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.10/ext/openssl/openssl.c#L6482) and in that case the `openssl_encrypt()` call will fail if the plaintext length is not a multiple of 8 bytes.

Comment: Yes, I agree with everything you said except for that one remark. For educational purposes, I have written an additional answer that briefly touches on that subject as well, but otherwise supports your answer.

Comment: Thanks :-). One point in favor of the PHP OpenSSL wrapper API: the documentation for the function [openssl_encrypt()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) mentions `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` and not `OPENSSL_NO_PADDING`. Likewise, `openssl_public_encrypt()` mentions `OPENSSL_NO_PADDING` and not `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING`. But still, this is confusing to everybody.

Answer (score 4):

I do not have much to add to [Maarten's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52540984/1380680), except I thought it would be nice to show some the code that illustrates his words.

`mcrypt` adds zeroes to fill up the plaintext to a multiple of the BF blocksize of 8 bytes, which can be shown by printing hexdumps of both the plaintext and the decrypted ciphertext:

```
$key = "supersecretkey";
$data = "foobar";
$ctxt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
$ptxt = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $key, $ctxt, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
echo bin2hex($data).PHP_EOL;
echo bin2hex($ptxt).PHP_EOL;
```

gives the following hexdumps:

```
666f6f626172
666f6f6261720000
```

`openssl` by default uses PKCS#5 padding which, in this case, adds 2 bytes with value 2 at the end of the block:

```
$key = "supersecretkey";
$data = "foobar";
$opts = OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_DONT_ZERO_PAD_KEY;
$ctxt = openssl_encrypt($data, 'BF-ECB', $key, $opts);
$ptxt = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $key, $ctxt, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
echo bin2hex($data).PHP_EOL;
echo bin2hex($ptxt).PHP_EOL;
```

gives

```
666f6f626172
666f6f6261720202
```

The ciphertext for `mcrypt` and `openssl` can be made consistent by manually adding the padding bytes. Note the `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` options and the addition of `"\0\0"`:

```
$key = "supersecretkey";
$data = "foobar";
$ctxt_mc = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
$opts = OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_DONT_ZERO_PAD_KEY | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING;
$ctxt_os = openssl_encrypt($data."\0\0", 'BF-ECB', $key, $opts);
echo bin2hex($ctxt_mc).PHP_EOL;
echo bin2hex($ctxt_os).PHP_EOL;
```

gives:

```
e73d2adf1367a24c
e73d2adf1367a24c
```

Alternatively, manually inserting PKCS#5 padding bytes at the end when using `mcrypt`:

```
$key = "supersecretkey";
$data = "foobar";
$ctxt_mc = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $key, $data."\2\2", MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
$opts = OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_DONT_ZERO_PAD_KEY;
$ctxt_os = openssl_encrypt($data, 'BF-ECB', $key, $opts);
echo bin2hex($ctxt_mc).PHP_EOL;
echo bin2hex($ctxt_os).PHP_EOL;
```

gives

```
d73caa6afabbb029
d73caa6afabbb029
```

Finally, trying to invoke `openssl_encrypt()` with padding disabled and a length that is not a multiple of the block size:

```
$key = "supersecretkey";
$data = "foobar";
$opts = OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_DONT_ZERO_PAD_KEY | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING;
$ctxt = openssl_encrypt($data, 'BF-ECB', $key, $opts);
echo(openssl_error_string().PHP_EOL)
```

gives

```
error:0607F08A:digital envelope routines:EVP_EncryptFinal_ex:data not multiple of block length
```

Remark: the name `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` is confusing, but it means "no padding". You might be tempted to use the flag [`OPENSSL_NO_PADDING`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.2.10/ext/openssl/openssl.c#L1486), but that one is not intended to be used with `openssl_encrypt()`. Its value is [3](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_2n/crypto/rsa/rsa.h#L309), which is the same as `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING`. In stead, [it is intended for use with asymmetric cryptography](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php).