# Why are mcrypt and openssl_encrypt not giving the same results for blowfish with ecb if password is shorter than 16 chars?

Tags: php, openssl, mcrypt

I've read the general suggesstions:
[mcrypt is deprecated, what is the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272257/mcrypt-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative) and 
[PHP7.1 mcrypt alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41740600/php7-1-mcrypt-alternative)

And tested the following solutions:
[Migrating mcrypt with Blowfish and ECB to OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52537909/migrating-mcrypt-with-blowfish-and-ecb-to-openssl) and
[php: mcrypt_encrypt to openssl_encrypt, and OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41181905/php-mcrypt-encrypt-to-openssl-encrypt-and-openssl-zero-padding-problems?rq=1)

They ain't work. This is my used code:

```
$message = "My secret message";
$key = "mysecretpasswor"; // <- if you add one more character here, it's working
$iv = "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0";

$message_padded = $message;

if(strlen($message_padded) % 8) {
  $message_padded = str_pad($message_padded, strlen($message_padded) + 8 - strlen($message_padded) % 8, "\0");
}

$encrypted_mcrypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $key, $message, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
$encrypted_openssl = openssl_encrypt($message_padded, "bf-ecb", $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_NO_PADDING);

printf("%s => %s\n", $message, base64_encode($encrypted_mcrypt));
printf("%s => %s\n", $message_padded, base64_encode($encrypted_openssl));
```

Using something like "DES-EDE3-CBC" as encryption method does work. But I cannot change the encryption that's used. I've to migrate the old code to new code. There sometimes keys used, that are shorter than 16 characters.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `OPENSSL_NO_PADDING` is not supposed to be used with `openssl_encrypt()`. [Its documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) mentions `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING`, which (confusingly) means 'no padding'. That is what you want.

`OPENSSL_NO_PADDING` is [intended for use with asymmetric cryptography](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php). By coincidence it has a value of 3 which is equal to `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING`. This the reason why you can use it incorrectly without consequence (in this case).

Your ciphertexts are different because the function `openssl_encrypt()` in `bf-ecb` mode by default will pad your key with `\0`'s if its length is less than 16 bytes. This is not required for blowfish and `mcrypt_encrypt()` does not do that. In order to switch off that behavior, use the flag `OPENSSL_DONT_ZERO_PAD_KEY` when calling `openssl_encrypt()`. Since this flag does not seem to be documented, you will have to go to [the source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.3.1/ext/openssl/openssl.c#L1526) to learn about it :-). Or read [Bug #72362   OpenSSL Blowfish encryption is incorrect for short keys](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=72362).

With this, the correct invocation of `openssl_encrypt()` becomes:

```
$opts = OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING | OPENSSL_DONT_ZERO_PAD_KEY;
$encrypted_openssl = openssl_encrypt($message_padded, "bf-ecb", $key, $opts);
```

Testing it:

```
$ php bf.php
My secret message => JPO/tvAqFD2KCTqfv0l8uWLfPUWdZIxQ
My secret message => JPO/tvAqFD2KCTqfv0l8uWLfPUWdZIxQ
```