# How to decrypt with as3crypto string encrypted with by aes-256-ecb?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, aes, ecb, as3crypto

String is encrypted with php as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3422787/1826684).
It can be decrypted by [this](http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/decrypt/) with parameters: Rijndael-256, ECB and Base64. But it cannot be decrypted by my ActionScript code:

```
var text:String = "Some data";
var key:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
key.writeUTFBytes("SomePassword");
key.position = key.length;
for (var i:int = key.length; i < 256 / 8; i++) {
    key.writeByte(0);
}
var pad:IPad = new NullPad();
var cipher:ICipher = Crypto.getCipher("aes-256-ecb", key, pad);
var data:ByteArray = Base64.decodeToByteArray(text);
cipher.decrypt(data);
trace(data.toString());
```

**UPD:**

"It cannot be decrypted" means I get wrong plain text.

In php plain text is encrypted by aes-256-ecb firstly. Then it is encoded by Base64. In ActionScript these stepsarw being done in reverse order.

**UPD2:**

Test for encoding-decoding:

```
var key:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
key.writeUTFBytes("Some password");
key.position = key.length;
for (var i:int = key.length; i < 256 / 8; i++) {
    key.writeByte(0);
}
trace(key.toString());
var data:ByteArray = new ByteArray();//plain text
data.writeUTFBytes("Hello, my dear World! Hello, the Sun! Hello, the Moon! Hello! Hello! Hello!");
var pad:IPad = new NullPad();
var cipher:ICipher = Crypto.getCipher("aes-256-ecb", key, pad);
trace(data.toString());//trace plain text
cipher.encrypt(data);
trace(data.toString());//trace encrypted text
cipher.decrypt(data);
trace(data.toString());//trace decrypted text
```

The output after halting at `cihper.encrypt(data)` is:

```
Some password
Hello, my dear World! Hello, the Sun! Hello, the Moon! Hello! Hello! Hello!
[Fault] exception, information=Error: Error #2030: End of file found.
```

**UPD3:**

It works right with PKCS5 padding:

```
var pad:IPad = new PKCS5();
var cipher:ICipher = Crypto.getCipher("aes-256-ecb", key, pad);
pad.setBlockSize(cipher.getBlockSize());
```

Output is:

```
Some password
Hello, my dear World! Hello, the Sun! Hello, the Moon! Hello! Hello! Hello!
$ú^{±àÙ[pm|x¿9¡ÃZsI D¾`©4¾þÂõ,J
('èfÑk1ôì&­ªQƆfbÇåòþ§VµÄs   ¦p<iÿ
Hello, my dear World! Hello, the Sun! Hello, the Moon! Hello! Hello! Hello!
```

**UPD4:**

For data gotten from php (as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3422787/1826684)) code with PKCS5 padding running halts [here](https://github.com/timkurvers/as3-crypto/blob/master/src/com/hurlant/crypto/symmetric/PKCS5.as#L34). And with Null padding it doesn't halts but decrypted data is wrong.

Comment: "*it cannot be decrypted*" is not a good error description. Do you get the wrong plaintext? Do you get an error?

Comment: `text` should be get from server by URLLoader.

Comment: This means the implementation of algorithm is different in PHP and AS3Crypto. Try another algorith, like rc4 or BlowFish.

Comment: Try to encrypt the same string with same pass in PHP and AS3Crypto, what you will get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the code in your last post:

```
return trim(
    base64_encode(
        mcrypt_encrypt(
            MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
            $sSecretKey, $sValue, 
            MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, 
            mcrypt_create_iv(
                mcrypt_get_iv_size(
                    MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, 
                    MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
                ), 
                MCRYPT_RAND)
            )
        )
    );
```

MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 isn't AES. MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 is. Rijndael has variable block sizes.  AES is a subset of Rijndael with fixed block sizes.

The number after MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_* is referring to the block size. So MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 is Rijndael with a 256-bit block size.  MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 is Rijndael with a 128-block size, aka AES.

Also, if you're going to use MCRYPT_MODE_ECB I'd replace the mcrypt_create_iv() call with an empty string of a bunch of null bytes.  ECB as a block mode does not use an IV.

Finally, my own personal recommendation, since this is all very counter intuitive with mcrypt, is to use [phpseclib, a pure PHP AES implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/crypt/examples.html).

Comment: So I can't decrypt RIJNDAEL_256_ECB by as3crypto?

Comment: But phpseclib offers AES-256-ECB.

Comment: Decrypting RIJNDAEL_256_ECB with as3crypto is probably not possible.

Comment: As for phpseclib's offering AES-256-ECB... both AES and Rijndael support variable key sizes.  Only Rijndael supports variable block sizes as well.

Comment: Will using of MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB for PHP and aes-128-ecb for as3crypto (with 128-bit keys for both) solve the problem?