# MySQL AES_DECRYPT in PHP doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, mysql, aes, crud

Using [xcrud data manipulation](http://xcrud.com/documentation/index.html#0_data_manipulation) and more specifically from where it says "Database instanse In all external files you can use xcrud database instanse:", I have my table displaying using `$xcrud = Xcrud::get_instance()->table('users');`.

Now the issue is that all my data is encrypted using `AES_ENCRYPT` with a `$salt`. I need to do an `AES_DECRYPT` but unsure where or how I can go about it with `xcrud` methods.

Can I even go about using the MySQL `AES_DECRYPT` function purely in PHP instead and just use a callback in the `functions.php`?

Edit: I've tried this method in PHP however it is displaying weird characters (���,��ŝA����,�At�nz��M�F)...

```
function mysql_aes_key($key)
{
    $new_key = str_repeat(chr(0), 16);
    for($i=0,$len=strlen($key);$i<$len;$i++)
    {
        $new_key[$i%16] = $new_key[$i%16] ^ $key[$i];
    }
    return $new_key;
}

function decrypt_info($value)
{
    $key = mysql_aes_key('mysalt');
    $value = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $value, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv( mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
    return rtrim($value, "0..10");
}

function decrypt_name($value)
{
    $decrypted = decrypt_info($value);
    return $decrypted;
}
```

Comment: FWIW, salting is something you do with one-way hashing functions. There is no benefit to using a salt with a block encryption functions like AES.

Comment: Thanks @BillKarwin appreciate the "FWIW" :) any idea though what the issue is here?

Comment: What kind of padding are you applying to the key? MySQL pads the key using PKCS7.

Comment: Thanks @Jack I'm actually using no padding. When I do an `INSERT` it's literally like this: `AES_ENCRYPT('".$email."','".$salt."')`

Comment: I don't have any insight into why your strings are not decrypting correctly. But if it were me, I would decrypt using the same interface I used to encrypt. So if I used MySQL's `AES_ENCRYPT()`, then I would stick with MySQL's `AES_DECRYPT()`. The reason is that I don't know if the implementation of the encryption algorithm (and its options like padding) is necessarily the same between MySQL and PHP. Or even if it is true today, perhaps some later version of either MySQL or PHP will change its implementation.

Comment: I mean the padding you apply in `mysql_aes_key()` seems to be wrong; the key should be padded with `CHR(16 - strlen($salt) % 16)`; see also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17039628/aes-encryption-in-mysql-and-php).

Comment: Thanks @BillKarwin and @Jack - @Jack could you please provide the updated `mysql_aes_key` function as an answer? Thank you!