# What is the equivalent of MySQL's AES_ENCRYPT("AES-256-CBC") in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, aes

What is the equivalent of MySQL's AES_ENCRYPT ECB method in PHP? After searching for quite a while here in SO, I only found topics with regards to MySQL's AES with "ECB" method and not "CBC".

Should I use `openssl`? `mcrypt`? Or is there any chance that the encryption made in PHP could be decrypted with the use of MySQL and vice versa?

Comment: According to the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html) its `RIJNDAEL-128`. And on the question if you should use the abandoned software `mcrypt` vs `openssl`, well. Your choice.

Comment: I have an `openssl` solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49926582/2137316.  Doesn't quite answer the question here, but it may help.