# encrypting ids of records

Tags: php, security, encryption, uniqueidentifier

In this site we have `id`s for `categories`. These are essentially the `primary key` of `categories` table. They are sequential and auto-incremental.

This `id` is passed around the site as hidden field, session value etc. In the backend whenever a form is submitted, or some db update is done etc, the `id` is validated to make sure that it has not been tampered with.

```
$id = $this->getPostField(cat_id);
$id = validate($id); //perform checks on the id field
```

I could encrypt/decrypt the id so that even if anyone looks at the hidden field he couldn't really understand its value. However my question is - is it really necessary or will I be just adding a layer of complexity which only increases the overhead without too much value add?

```
$id = $this->getPostField(cat_id);
$id = validate(keyDecrypt($id)); //perform checks on the decrypted id field
```

I guess why I am asking this is because the id is not a very sensitive data like a credit card or social sec number. It does not really matter that the user can see it if he reads hidden fields. As long as I am validating it in the backend I am assuming I should be fine (?)

Comment: I think this help u.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422759/php-aes-encrypt-decrypt

Comment: Are you familiar with the term security through obscurity

Comment: @kingkero Are you familiar with the term - "why don't you give a complete answer"?

Comment: @Aminul - thanks for that link. I guess I can find a way to do the encrypt/decrypt. But if I am checking the id properly in the backend, does it really matter if I encrypt the number or not? I mean, it is not an email/password/credit card number or any such important/sensitive piece of data.

Comment: @open_sourse - no it does not really matter. if any one could get the id he/she could understand why it is needed and which table it belongs to..

Answer (score 1):

You can, too, add an uniqid to every Category, and check if `id + uniqid` are linked to a category. This uniqid can even be the slug, for example

But it looks like to be an overhead, if someone really wan't to change something client-side, it is still possible. As long as you check server side, it's good. And as you save it in the session, it's quite fast and easy.

As said above in comments, it's *security through obscurity*, and it won't protect you for long if the attacker really wan't to.

It's up to you to see if it's valuable to use the `id`, another field, or encrypt it ... (you may also hash it, as the id is stored in session :-))

Answer (score 0):

I don't consider this security through obscurity.

> if anyone looks at the hidden field he couldn't really understand its value.

There isn't much to understand in the first place. `id` itself doesn't have any useful information, it just refers to a particular record.

However, since it's an auto-increment integer, it exposes information like how many categories there are. Encrypting the `id`s with a key makes that meta information confidential, and it does so with a well-defined secret: the encryption key. This isn't security through obscurity, because even if people knew the exact scheme, they still couldn't figure out the category count without the key.