# Subsequent decrypt fails with file size 0

Tags: php, encryption

The following script works fine. The zip is encrypted, txt file created, and immediately decrypted successfully, and the new zip is created successfully.

However, if I run the decrypt portion only subsequently, it fails to decrypt the txt file. It returns an empty `$original_plaintext` variable and the final zip has size 0. The $key and $iv are not changed for the second run. Security is not the issue - I just need a scrambled text file and then need to be able to decrypt it later.

```
$key = "sometext";  
$iv = "someothertext";  
$cipher = "aes-128-gcm";
$tag = NULL;

$fileRoot = "sql_2018_11_10";

if (in_array($cipher, openssl_get_cipher_methods())) {
    // Encrypt
    $plaintext = file_get_contents("tmp/$fileRoot.zip");
    $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, $options=0, $iv, $tag);
    file_put_contents("tmp/enc_$fileRoot.txt", $ciphertext);

    // Decrypt
    $ciphertext = file_get_contents("tmp/enc_$fileRoot.txt");   
    $original_plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, $cipher, $key, $options=0, $iv, $tag);
    file_put_contents("tmp/uenc_$fileRoot.zip", $original_plaintext);
}
```

Comment: I have tried several different combinations of :
* Fixed IV and key
* Fixed and non-fixed IV and key
* Using zip and not using zip
Why in each case will it successfully decrypt if it is immediately after the encrypt, but not if it's decrypt only?
As for errors, I'm seeing error:0607A082:digital envelope routines:EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_key_length:invalid key length, but I'm using a 128-byte key, as recommended in the docs.
How do I get it to decrypt?

Comment: After more experimentation, I find that decrypt only works if it is preceded by an encrypt of the exact same text. Is this a PHP bug or am I missing something fundamental?