# How to do decrypt AES256 in backpack laravel

Tags: laravel-backpack

In one application where i am using backpack for admin dashboard. I am sending data(such as 'name', 'email') as encrypting AES256 to stored in the database. Now, I want to retrieve those data and show in the admin dashboard. But the problem is how will I decrypt those data values before showing in the dashboard ?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna decrypt your data from the database, you can use `accessors` in your models to modify the shown data.

So, in your `users` model add this function:

```
public function getNameAttribute($value) { 
    // Add decrypt methond in this function
    // $name = decrypt($value, 'password');

    return $name;
}

public function getEmailAttribute($value) { 
    // Add decrypt methond in this function
    // $email = decrypt($value, 'password');

    return $email;
}
```

I found the decrypt example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/46872528/8653054

Comment: Ok. I will implement this and tell you the result.