# how to encrypt and decrypt text in php

Tags: php

how to encrypt and decrypt  text in php

Comment: Try with Enigma. I think you can hook it to your webserver easily.

Comment: @klez the hard part will be breaking into the museum, though. And building the USB interface in there, at night, using only a flashlight.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

http://www.weberdev.com/get_example-4118.html

[Best way to use PHP to encrypt and decrypt passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289061/best-way-to-use-php-to-encrypt-and-decrypt)