# PHP encrypt/decrypt default_charset problem

Tags: php, string, encryption, unicode, ascii

I need to encrypt files at one computer and open it another one using PHP without external libraries. The code should work at both PHP4 and PHP5.

Encryption function makes str_split of the string and encodes each character (ord) using str_split of password. Then it makes chr and I get binary data. This binary data is encoded using base64_encode and I get ascii string.

I transfer this file to another computer who knows the password.
I make base64_decode and make decrypt.

The problem appeares sometimes because the first computer has ASCII default_charset and second has UTF-8.
That's why nth-char $temproraryBinaryString[$n-1] may have different values at these computers.

Can I ask PHP to treat all strings as ASCII if I cannot control php.ini at any of this computers?

Comment: Don’t reinvent the wheel but use an existing encryption algorithm.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to use PHP to encrypt and decrypt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289061/best-way-to-use-php-to-encrypt-and-decrypt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrongly flagged as duplicated but it's not, what you're talking is **encoding** not encryption, just try:

```
$ascii = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $string);
```

This should give you a clean ASCII string to work on with `str_split()` and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the discussion on this post, as it talks about two-way encryption, using [PHP mcrypt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php), which is what you should use.  [Two-way encryption: I need to store passwords that can be retrieved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089841/php-2-way-encryption-i-need-to-store-passwords-that-can-be-retrieved)

Comment: + oned for mcrypt, just be aware the 2 servers need the same php versions.  Too lazy to look it up myself but I think the implementation or something changed between earlier version and 5.3.