# PHP two way crypting

Tags: php, encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to use PHP to encrypt and decrypt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289061/best-way-to-use-php-to-encrypt-and-decrypt)

I am new in Two Way crypting technology in PHP. I have used sha512 as one way hashing, but now I really need two way ecryption. and I don't know where to start. Can you tell me which method I must use for the most security? and can you give me simple "hello world" example?

***Edited***

Thank you for all answers, I found mCrypt as an key for my problem, but I can use a lot of methods like MCRYPT_3DES, MCRYPT_CAST_128, MCRYPT_CAST_256.... so what to use?

Comment: try searching.  There is plenty of information out there on how to do encryption with PHP.  [Here On SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089841/php-2-way-encryption-i-need-to-store-passwords-that-can-be-retrieved/5093422#5093422), [On PHP.Net](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php), [Another On SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289061/best-way-to-use-php-to-encrypt-and-decrypt)

Comment: sha512 is one way crypting system, that I use in PHP, I have googled, but is mCrypt installed as default in servers? and which method is most safe from mCrypt methods?

Comment: @user1228636: No it's not.  It's a cryptographic hashing function.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948322/fundamental-difference-between-hashing-and-encryption-algorithms/4948393#4948393) for more info

Comment: There is plant of methods that I can use in mCrypt, can you suggest me the most secure one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using openssl functions for what you need: [openssl_public_encrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php) and [openssl_private_decrypt](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-private-decrypt.php).

To use them you will have to generate yourself a RSA public/private key pair.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but can you suggest 1 or 2 more methods too, to have the choosing opportunity

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix up hashing with encryption.

You could use the [mcrypt-expansion](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.examples.php), its well documented, and they have some good examples, like this one:

```
 $key = "this is a secret key";
 $input = "This is a top secrep message.";

 $td = mcrypt_module_open('tripledes', '', 'ecb', '');
 $iv = mcrypt_create_iv (mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND);
 mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
 $encrypted_data = mcrypt_generic($td, $input);
 mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
 mcrypt_module_close($td);
```

There are many other methods out there, [openssl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php) is one of them.

Comment: I can use a lot of methods like MCRYPT_3DES, MCRYPT_CAST_128, MCRYPT_CAST_256.... so what to use?

Comment: Whatever you want. The library supports a few algorithms, see here for more details: http://mcrypt.hellug.gr/#_mcrypt. Currently it seems to support BLOWFISH, TWOFISH, DES, TripleDES, 3-WAY, SAFER, LOKI97, GOST, RC2, MARS, RIJNDAEL, SERPENT, CAST, ARCFOUR and WAKE. I'm not an expert on the topic, so I'm not sure which one is safer than others (I'd advise against using DES).

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of mcrypt which comes with PHP

This is the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) for Mcrypt (Manual is always the best to start with)

Since you have asked for an easy hello-world type. Have a look here in this [link](http://t4vn.net/tutorials/showtutorials/An-Introduction-to-Mcrypt-and-PHP.html).

Comment: Yes there is manual about mCrypt but with mCrypt, I think, I can use a lot of methods like MCRYPT_3DES, MCRYPT_CAST_128, MCRYPT_CAST_256.... so what to use?