# How to log in with hashed passwords in PHP using Yii Framework?

Tags: php, yii, hash

I have another application sending me a hashed password and am trying to achieve a direct login to my own application once I receive it but Yii's Login function uses an _identity variable that validates a username and an unhashed password. 
Does anyone know of a way around this so that I can achieve a direct login?
This is my sample code:

```
public function actionPortalLogin()
{
    $model=new LoginForm;
    $model->username = 'username';
    $model->password = 'randomHashedPassword';
    $model->Login();
    if (Yii::app()->user->returnUrl == "/myapp/index.php") {

            $this->redirect("/myapp/index.php/home/userHome");
        }

    else {
        $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
    }
}

public function Login()
{
    if($this->_identity===null)
    {
        $this->_identity=new UserIdentity($this->username,$this->password);
        $this->_identity->authenticate();
    }
    if($this->_identity->errorCode===UserIdentity::ERROR_NONE)
    {
        $duration=$this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0; // 30 days
        Yii::app()->user->login($this->_identity,$duration);
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Fairly straight forward. Ideally, instead of the first few lines, i'd receive a username and pass from another application and would then be able to perform the login using my own app but like i said, this doesn't seem to be working. Does anyone else know any workarounds to doing this or maybe a way that yii can verify hashed passwords and use it to perform a login without ever having to decrypt it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send encrypted password, then you will need to able decrypt it before call user identity.

```
$model = new LoginForm;
$mode->password = LoginForm::decryptPassword('encrypted password value here');
```

Solutions about encrypt and decrypt you will found there:

[Two-way encryption: I need to store passwords that can be retrieved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089841/two-way-encryption-i-need-to-store-passwords-that-can-be-retrieved)

[Best way to use PHP to encrypt and decrypt passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289061/best-way-to-use-php-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-passwords)

[How do you Encrypt and Decrypt a PHP String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16600708/how-do-you-encrypt-and-decrypt-a-php-string)