# Yii2 - encrypt password for db connection

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

How to encrypt the database password ?

```
return [
  'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
  'dsn' => 'pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=database',
  'username' => 'user',
  'password' => 'abcPassword',
  'charset' => 'utf8',
];
```

Comment: @ vijay nathji  do you have any sample that I can refer ?

Comment: password_hash method will fullfill your requirenments @kasam

Answer (score 0):

Yii2 comes with user module in advanced setup. See how it store user passwords in encrypted way.

You can use setPassword() method in User Model to get hashed passwords.

```
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password_hash = Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password);
}
```

and call this method before saving model data.

```
public function signup()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        $user = new User();
        $user->username = $this->username;
        $user->email = $this->email;
        $user->setPassword($this->password);
        $user->generateAuthKey();
        if ($user->save()) {
            return $user;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Also look at the Yii2 doc for passwords =>http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-passwords.html and 
authentication.=> http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authentication.html

Comment: Actually what I mean is to encrypt the password that lets you connect to the database.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089841/two-way-encryption-i-need-to-store-passwords-that-can-be-retrieved

This link might be helful to  you

Answer (score 0):

Try Via This way.. I didn't tasted it.. but might be helpful to you.

```
$database = 'mydb';
    $username = 'abc';
    $password = '1234';

$config['components'] = [
    'db' => [
        'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=192.168.*.*;dbname=' . $database,
        'username' => $username,

        'password' => md5($password);    // Try this 



        'password' => Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($password); // Or Else try this

        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ]

    return config;
```