# How to securly store information I need to retrieve?

Tags: encryption

I can't use a hash, because I need to retrieve the information. I guess encryption would work, but here's my issue: I need a key for encryption to work. I need to store that key somewhere. If someone gets his hand on the key, my encryption is useless. So what's the point of encrypting, since a data leak ruins everything anyway?

Comment: Yes, you have to store the key securely (or not at all; sometimes the key can be derived from ephemeral data, such as a password), else the encryption is pointless.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two-way encryption: I need to store passwords that can be retrieved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089841/two-way-encryption-i-need-to-store-passwords-that-can-be-retrieved)