# Safest method to save passwords

Tags: laravel, security, passwords

What is the safest method to save a password in the database, knowing that the password should be decrypted too in order to be able to connect with the WordPress website?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two-way encryption: I need to store passwords that can be retrieved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089841/two-way-encryption-i-need-to-store-passwords-that-can-be-retrieved)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289061/best-way-to-use-php-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-passwords

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-passwords-using-php/