# Best way of encrypting text to store in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database, encryption

I want to know the best way of storing text in a database and encrypting it so as to prevent others (admin) from reading it. I'm allowing users to write (up-to) paragraphs of plain text and then storing in a database. This text is then displayed back to the user in their account. This means that I will have to be able to decrypt the data once i've encrypt it and stored it in the database.
(I have created the project using PHP)

Thanks

Comment: Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289061/best-way-to-use-php-to-encrypt-and-decrypt

Answer (score 2):

[`AES_ENCRYPT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_aes-encrypt) and `AES_DECRYPT` are easy ways to encrypt/decrypt strings without writing the code yourself, available in MySql 5 upwards.

Be aware that the output of `AES_ENCRYPT` is a binary string, which needs to be stored in columns of a binary data type (most likely the appropriate one would be `BLOB`) instead of text types such as `TEXT` or `VARCHAR` that you would normally use for text data.

The problem is that you are going to have to store the encryption key *somewhere*, and you somehow have to keep the admin from accessing it. I don't know if that will be possible (admin of *what* exactly?)

Comment: How do you propose to store, pull, rotate, and otherwise manage encryption keys, in such a way that others can't read encrypted data?

Comment: @Justice: I don't. And it would be impossible to make such a proposal without having much more detailed knowledge of the application in question.

Comment: @Justice - It depends on the requirements – Who do you mean by "others"? If its people with full access to the server, the only option is to use client-side (javascript) encryption. And even then they could modify the javascript code to not encrypt data, for example.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is [MCrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php). Also if you are wanting the data to be truly secure you will need to use HTTPS for transport as once the PHP script has decrypted the cipher text (when the user is accessing the text) the plain text is sent out through the NIC of the server. So a crafty admin or attacker could just sniff the trafic on the interface and log the traffic.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, you can't prevent admin from viewing these texts as he'll be able to read encryption password as well and decrypt them.

Comment: Really? Only if you store the password itself. If you only store the password hash the admin will not be able to decrypt the text.

Comment: but we're talking about encryption here, not hashing

Answer (score -1):

1. Use a save connection (https) so
   your admin can not get the password
   from the logs.
2. Use MCript to encrypt decrypt the
   data with the users password.
3. Decrypt the data with the users
   password.

There is however one BIG drawback:

You will have to store the users password in cleartext in the session, so you MUST take care that session data is not stored in logs, the database, etc...

If your admin has access to the php code it is a matter of seconds to hack this.

The only case where this will work is if your Admin can access the database and the backend BUT NOT the code.