# Encrypting - Decrypt same variable - PHP

Tags: php, function, variables, encryption

If my variable looks like this:

```
$name = "John";
```

and I want the above variable, to be encrypted to something like:

```
 encrypt($name) //Will output something like: AIfzx353HA7f (Just random chars)
```

And then, be able to decrypt it, so it will output John again.

```
decrypt($name) //Will output John
```

Is this possible to do with PHP?

Comment: Possible duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289061/best-way-to-use-php-to-encrypt-and-decrypt

Comment: -1 because a quick google search leads me directly to the duplicated question: http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=encrypt+decrypt+php&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use different types of algorithms to do this. Maybe you can take a look at Mcrypt [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php).
(in particular mcrypt_encrypt and mcrypt_decrypt)

Answer (score 1):

There's [`mcrypt`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) extension that supports a variety of cryptographic functions.