# PHP Base64 encode with salt string

Tags: php, encryption

How can I encode string using `PHP Base64_encode` function with passing some `Salt String`

I don't want others to hack my string. If some one is having little knowledge in php, he can easily hack if I directly encode string. Because this is the only function allow you to decode encoded content. As far as I know.

In the tutorials I see above function will accept only one parameter.

Any Help ?

Comment: If you want to *properly* encrypt a string, don't use base64. Use a proper encryption method instead

Comment: What method you are talking about ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to use PHP to encrypt and decrypt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289061/best-way-to-use-php-to-encrypt-and-decrypt)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use [mcrypt](http://php.net/mcrypt) php extension.

Comment: This is no longer recommended, use Libsodium - A PHP extension. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272257/mcrypt-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative