# mcrypt is deprecated, what is the alternative?

Tags: php, encryption, passwords, php-7, mcrypt

The mcrypt-extension is [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.deprecated.php#migration71.deprecated.ext-mcrypt) will be removed in PHP 7.2 according to the comment posted [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=73734). So I am looking for an alternative way to encrypt passwords.

Right now I am using something like

```
mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, md5($key, true), $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv)
```

I need your opinion for the best/strongest way to encrypt passwords, the encrypted password should of course supported by PHP 7.xx and should also be decryptable because my customers do want to have an option to 'recover' their passwords without generating a new one.

Comment: Why do you need to encrypt/decrypt passwords? Why not just hash them with `password_hash` and verify them with `password_verify`?

Comment: *"the encrypted password should also be decryptable"* - why? doesn't sound too safe. Any special reason?

Comment: Where did you hear of mcrypt_encrypt being removed in php 7? https://wiki.php.net/rfc/remove_deprecated_functionality_in_php7 shows *"mcrypt_ecb, mcrypt_cbc, mcrypt_cfb and mcrypt_ofb (since PHP 5.5, but documented as deprecated earlier; use mcrypt_encrypt and mcrypt_decrypt instead)"* - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php shows (PHP 4 >= 4.0.2, PHP 5, PHP 7)

Comment: Thanks for the quicks reply's. I edited the first post to make it more clear.

Comment: *"because my customers do want to have option to 'recover' their passwords without generating a new one."* - That isn't safe and they should be given the option to reset their passwords instead.

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: @Fred-ii- PHP 7.2 have removed it mcrypt, in PHP 7 & 7.1 it have a status of soon will be removed or changed.

Comment: @TheCrazyProfessor Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking, that's "if" you're asking something or just to let me know of it being removed; which I knew *thanks* :-)

Comment: From the php manual -> This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 7.1.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged.             

Alternative is sodium -> http://php.net/manual/en/book.sodium.php

Comment: use openssl like this http://helpdoc.info/mcrypt_rijndael_128-is-not-working-with-php-7-x-with-ccavenue/

Comment: "my customers do want to have an option to 'recover' their passwords without generating a new one" is as same as store password in plaintext. It's a bad practice. If customer can recover the password, so does any attacker.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

It's best practice to hash passwords so they are not decryptable. This makes things slightly more difficult for attackers that may have gained access to your database or files.

If you must encrypt your data and have it decryptable, a guide to secure encryption/decryption is available at https://paragonie.com/white-paper/2015-secure-php-data-encryption. To summarize that link:

- Use [Libsodium](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium) - A PHP extension
- If you can't use Libsodium, use [defuse/php-encryption](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) - Straight PHP code
- If you can't use Libsodium or defuse/php-encryption, use [OpenSSL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php) - A lot of servers will already have this installed. If not, it can be compiled with --with-openssl[=DIR]

Comment: Should first try openssl because it is very common, where libsodium isn't. Raw php shouldn't be used unless all native extension are out if question

Comment: even though openssl is very common, it seems that php 7 will be using libsodium for its core cryptography    https://securityintelligence.com/news/php-will-incorporate-libsodium-for-crypto/

Comment: Note there is a library called `Sodium-compat` (https://github.com/paragonie/sodium_compat) which works in PHP >= 5.2.4

Answer (score 35):

As suggested by [@rqLizard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43258754/55075), you can use [`openssl_encrypt`](http://php.net/openssl_encrypt)/[`openssl_decrypt`](http://php.net/openssl_decrypt) PHP functions instead which provides a much 
 better alternative to implement [AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) (The Advanced Encryption Standard) also known as Rijndael encryption.

As per the following [Scott's comment at php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php#117667):

> If you're writing code to encrypt/encrypt data in 2015, you should use `openssl_encrypt()` and `openssl_decrypt()`. The underlying library (`libmcrypt`) has been abandoned since 2007, and performs far worse than OpenSSL (which leverages `AES-NI` on modern processors and is cache-timing safe).
>
> Also, `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` is not `AES-256`, it's a different variant of the Rijndael block cipher. If you want `AES-256` in `mcrypt`, you have to use `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` with a 32-byte key. OpenSSL makes it more obvious which mode you are using (i.e. `aes-128-cbc` vs `aes-256-ctr`).
>
> OpenSSL also uses PKCS7 padding with CBC mode rather than mcrypt's NULL byte padding. Thus, mcrypt is more likely to make your code vulnerable to padding oracle attacks than OpenSSL.
>
> Finally, if you are not authenticating your ciphertexts (Encrypt Then MAC), you're doing it wrong.

Further reading:

- [Using Encryption and Authentication Correctly (for PHP developers)](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/using-encryption-and-authentication-correctly).
- [If You're Typing the Word MCRYPT Into Your PHP Code, You're Doing It Wrong](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong).

### Code examples

#### Example #1

> AES Authenticated Encryption in GCM mode example for PHP 7.1+

```
<?php
//$key should have been previously generated in a cryptographically safe way, like openssl_random_pseudo_bytes
$plaintext = "message to be encrypted";
$cipher = "aes-128-gcm";
if (in_array($cipher, openssl_get_cipher_methods()))
{
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher);
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
    $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, $options=0, $iv, $tag);
    //store $cipher, $iv, and $tag for decryption later
    $original_plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, $cipher, $key, $options=0, $iv, $tag);
    echo $original_plaintext."\n";
}
?>
```

#### Example #2

> AES Authenticated Encryption example for PHP 5.6+

```
<?php
//$key previously generated safely, ie: openssl_random_pseudo_bytes
$plaintext = "message to be encrypted";
$ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher="AES-128-CBC");
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivlen);
$ciphertext_raw = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
$hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, $key, $as_binary=true);
$ciphertext = base64_encode( $iv.$hmac.$ciphertext_raw );

//decrypt later....
$c = base64_decode($ciphertext);
$ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length($cipher="AES-128-CBC");
$iv = substr($c, 0, $ivlen);
$hmac = substr($c, $ivlen, $sha2len=32);
$ciphertext_raw = substr($c, $ivlen+$sha2len);
$original_plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext_raw, $cipher, $key, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
$calcmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $ciphertext_raw, $key, $as_binary=true);
if (hash_equals($hmac, $calcmac))//PHP 5.6+ timing attack safe comparison
{
    echo $original_plaintext."\n";
}
?>
```

#### Example #3

Based on above examples, I've changed the following code which aims at encrypting user's session id:

```
class Session {

  /**
   * Encrypts the session ID and returns it as a base 64 encoded string.
   *
   * @param $session_id
   * @return string
   */
  public function encrypt($session_id) {
    // Get the MD5 hash salt as a key.
    $key = $this->_getSalt();
    // For an easy iv, MD5 the salt again.
    $iv = $this->_getIv();
    // Encrypt the session ID.
    $encrypt = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $session_id, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
    // Base 64 encode the encrypted session ID.
    $encryptedSessionId = base64_encode($encrypt);
    // Return it.
    return $encryptedSessionId;
  }

  /**
   * Decrypts a base 64 encoded encrypted session ID back to its original form.
   *
   * @param $encryptedSessionId
   * @return string
   */
  public function decrypt($encryptedSessionId) {
    // Get the MD5 hash salt as a key.
    $key = $this->_getSalt();
    // For an easy iv, MD5 the salt again.
    $iv = $this->_getIv();
    // Decode the encrypted session ID from base 64.
    $decoded = base64_decode($encryptedSessionId);
    // Decrypt the string.
    $decryptedSessionId = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $decoded, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv);
    // Trim the whitespace from the end.
    $session_id = rtrim($decryptedSessionId, "\0");
    // Return it.
    return $session_id;
  }

  public function _getIv() {
    return md5($this->_getSalt());
  }

  public function _getSalt() {
    return md5($this->drupal->drupalGetHashSalt());
  }

}
```

into:

```
class Session {

  const SESS_CIPHER = 'aes-128-cbc';

  /**
   * Encrypts the session ID and returns it as a base 64 encoded string.
   *
   * @param $session_id
   * @return string
   */
  public function encrypt($session_id) {
    // Get the MD5 hash salt as a key.
    $key = $this->_getSalt();
    // For an easy iv, MD5 the salt again.
    $iv = $this->_getIv();
    // Encrypt the session ID.
    $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($session_id, self::SESS_CIPHER, $key, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    // Base 64 encode the encrypted session ID.
    $encryptedSessionId = base64_encode($ciphertext);
    // Return it.
    return $encryptedSessionId;
  }

  /**
   * Decrypts a base 64 encoded encrypted session ID back to its original form.
   *
   * @param $encryptedSessionId
   * @return string
   */
  public function decrypt($encryptedSessionId) {
    // Get the Drupal hash salt as a key.
    $key = $this->_getSalt();
    // Get the iv.
    $iv = $this->_getIv();
    // Decode the encrypted session ID from base 64.
    $decoded = base64_decode($encryptedSessionId, TRUE);
    // Decrypt the string.
    $decryptedSessionId = openssl_decrypt($decoded, self::SESS_CIPHER, $key, $options=OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    // Trim the whitespace from the end.
    $session_id = rtrim($decryptedSessionId, '\0');
    // Return it.
    return $session_id;
  }

  public function _getIv() {
    $ivlen = openssl_cipher_iv_length(self::SESS_CIPHER);
    return substr(md5($this->_getSalt()), 0, $ivlen);
  }

  public function _getSalt() {
    return $this->drupal->drupalGetHashSalt();
  }

}
```

To clarify, above change is not a true conversion since the two encryption uses a different block size and a different encrypted data. Additionally, the default padding is different, `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL` only supports non-standard null padding. <sup>[@zaph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272257/mcrypt-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative/48120485?noredirect=1#comment83219538_48120485)</sup>

---

Additional notes (from the @zaph's comments):

- *Rijndael 128* (`MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128`) **is** equivalent to *AES*, however *Rijndael 256* (`MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256`) **is not** *AES-256* as the 256 specifies a block size of 256-bits, whereas *AES* has only one block size: 128-bits. So basically Rijndael with a block size of 256-bits (`MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256`) has been mistakenly named due to the choices by the [mcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mcrypt) developers. <sup>@zaph</sup>
- Rijndael with a block size of 256 may be less secure than with a block size of 128-bits because the latter has had much more reviews and uses. Secondly, interoperability is hindered in that while AES is generally available, where Rijndael with a block size of 256-bits is not.
- Encryption with different block sizes for Rijndael produces different encrypted data.

  For example, `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` (not equivalent to `AES-256`) defines a different variant of the Rijndael block cipher with size of 256-bits and a key size based on the passed in key, where `aes-256-cbc` is Rijndael with a block size of 128-bits with a key size of 256-bits. Therefore they're using different block sizes which produces entirely different encrypted data as mcrypt uses the number to specify the block size, where OpenSSL used the number to specify the key size (AES only has one block size of 128-bits). So basically AES is Rijndael with a block size of 128-bits and key sizes of 128, 192 and 256 bits. Therefore it's better to use AES, which is called Rijndael 128 in OpenSSL.

Comment: In general using Rijndael with a block size of 256-bits is a mistake due to the choices by the mcrypt developers. Further Rijndael with a block size of 256 may be less secure that with a block size of 128-bits because the latter has had much more review and use. Additionally interoperability is hindered in that while AES is generally available Rijndael with a block size of 256-bits is not.

Comment: Why do you `$session_id = rtrim($decryptedSessionId, "\0");` ? Is it possible for `openssl_decrypt` to return some unwanted characters in the end ? What if the encrypted variable ends with 0 (i.e. `encrypt("abc0")` ?

Comment: @hiscalon `"\0"` isn't `"0"` but the NULL character, whose ASCII code is 0x00 (hexadecimal 0).

Answer (score 24):

As detailed by other answers here, the best solution I found is using OpenSSL. It is built into PHP and you don't need any external library. Here are simple examples:

To encrypt:

```
function encrypt($key, $payload) {
  $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-256-cbc'));
  $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($payload, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, 0, $iv);
  return base64_encode($encrypted . '::' . $iv);
}
```

To decrypt:

```
function decrypt($key, $garble) {
    list($encrypted_data, $iv) = explode('::', base64_decode($garble), 2);
    return openssl_decrypt($encrypted_data, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, 0, $iv);
}
```

Reference link: https://www.shift8web.ca/2017/04/how-to-encrypt-and-execute-your-php-code-with-mcrypt/

Comment: A lot of good karma to you friend! Just one thing: if the password, for example, was encrypted with the old code, the new decrypt code will not be able to verify it. It has to be re-saved and encrypted with this new code.

Comment: A simple migration script would solve that issue. Use the old way to decrypt then the new way to encrypt and store. The alternative is adding a flag to the user's table and scripting in a forced password reset on all user accounts that need password changes.

Answer (score 14):

Pure-PHP implementation of Rijndael exists with [phpseclib](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib) available as composer package and works on PHP 7.3 (tested by me).

There's a page on the phpseclib docs, which [generates sample code](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/crypt/2.0/examples.html) after you input the basic variables (cipher, mode, key size, bit size). It outputs the following for Rijndael, ECB, 256, 256:

a code with mycrypt

```
$decoded = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, ENCRYPT_KEY, $term, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
```

works like this with the library

```
$rijndael = new \phpseclib\Crypt\Rijndael(\phpseclib\Crypt\Rijndael::MODE_ECB);
$rijndael->setKey(ENCRYPT_KEY);
$rijndael->setKeyLength(256);
$rijndael->disablePadding();
$rijndael->setBlockLength(256);

$decoded = $rijndael->decrypt($term);
```

* `$term` was `base64_decoded`

Comment: This answer coupled with the phpseclib mcrypt_compat polyfill package mentioned by someone else below is the solution

Answer (score 10):

You can use [phpseclib](https://github.com/phpseclib/mcrypt_compat) pollyfill package. You can not use open ssl or libsodium for encrypt/decrypt with rijndael 256.
Another issue, you don't need replacement any code.

Comment: This was super helpful thanks. Had to remove the php-mcrypt extension, and then this works like a charm.

Comment: I installed `mcrypt_compat` by running `composer require phpseclib/mcrypt_compat` but I still get `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mcrypt_get_key_size() in /app/kohana/classes/Kohana/Encrypt.php:124`
I'm using php `7.2.26` and Kohana framwork.
Is there any more steps to perform after installing it with composer?

Comment: Got it.
You have to add
`require APPPATH . '/vendor/autoload.php';`
to the bottom of `bootstrap.php`.

Comment: This is the most helpful answer that unblocked me. the mcrypt compat 2.0 + the phpseclib 3.0 works like a charm for a rijndael 256 mcrypt migration where swapping to AES is not an option due to decades of encrypted data

Answer (score 3):

You should use OpenSSL over `mcrypt` as it's actively developed and maintained. It provides better security, maintainability and portability. Secondly it performs AES encryption/decryption much faster. It uses PKCS7 padding by default, but you can specify `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` if you need it. To use with a 32-byte binary key, you can specify `aes-256-cbc` which is much obvious than `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128`.

Here is the code example using Mcrypt:

> Unauthenticated AES-256-CBC encryption library written in Mcrypt with PKCS7 padding.

```
/**
 * This library is unsafe because it does not MAC after encrypting
 */
class UnsafeMcryptAES
{
    const CIPHER = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128;

    public static function encrypt($message, $key)
    {
        if (mb_strlen($key, '8bit') !== 32) {
            throw new Exception("Needs a 256-bit key!");
        }
        $ivsize = mcrypt_get_iv_size(self::CIPHER);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($ivsize, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);

        // Add PKCS7 Padding
        $block = mcrypt_get_block_size(self::CIPHER);
        $pad = $block - (mb_strlen($message, '8bit') % $block, '8bit');
        $message .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);

        $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(
            MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
            $key,
            $message,
            MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
            $iv
        );

        return $iv . $ciphertext;
    }

    public static function decrypt($message, $key)
    {
        if (mb_strlen($key, '8bit') !== 32) {
            throw new Exception("Needs a 256-bit key!");
        }
        $ivsize = mcrypt_get_iv_size(self::CIPHER);
        $iv = mb_substr($message, 0, $ivsize, '8bit');
        $ciphertext = mb_substr($message, $ivsize, null, '8bit');

        $plaintext = mcrypt_decrypt(
            MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
            $key,
            $ciphertext,
            MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
            $iv
        );

        $len = mb_strlen($plaintext, '8bit');
        $pad = ord($plaintext[$len - 1]);
        if ($pad <= 0 || $pad > $block) {
            // Padding error!
            return false;
        }
        return mb_substr($plaintext, 0, $len - $pad, '8bit');
    }
}
```

And here is the version written using OpenSSL:

```
/**
 * This library is unsafe because it does not MAC after encrypting
 */
class UnsafeOpensslAES
{
    const METHOD = 'aes-256-cbc';

    public static function encrypt($message, $key)
    {
        if (mb_strlen($key, '8bit') !== 32) {
            throw new Exception("Needs a 256-bit key!");
        }
        $ivsize = openssl_cipher_iv_length(self::METHOD);
        $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($ivsize);

        $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt(
            $message,
            self::METHOD,
            $key,
            OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
            $iv
        );

        return $iv . $ciphertext;
    }

    public static function decrypt($message, $key)
    {
        if (mb_strlen($key, '8bit') !== 32) {
            throw new Exception("Needs a 256-bit key!");
        }
        $ivsize = openssl_cipher_iv_length(self::METHOD);
        $iv = mb_substr($message, 0, $ivsize, '8bit');
        $ciphertext = mb_substr($message, $ivsize, null, '8bit');

        return openssl_decrypt(
            $ciphertext,
            self::METHOD,
            $key,
            OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
            $iv
        );
    }
}
```

Source: [If You're Typing the Word MCRYPT Into Your PHP Code, You're Doing It Wrong](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong).

Answer (score 3):

I am using this on PHP 7.2.x, it's working fine for me:

```
public function make_hash($userStr){
        try{
            /** 
             * Used and tested on PHP 7.2x, Salt has been removed manually, it is now added by PHP 
             */
             return password_hash($userStr, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
            }catch(Exception $exc){
                $this->tempVar = $exc->getMessage();
                return false;
            }
        }
```

and then authenticate the hash with the following function:

```
public function varify_user($userStr,$hash){
        try{
            if (password_verify($userStr, $hash)) {
                 return true;
                }
            else {
                return false;
                }
            }catch(Exception $exc){
                $this->tempVar = $exc->getMessage();
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Example:

```
  //create hash from user string

 $user_password = $obj->make_hash2($user_key);
```

and to authenticate this hash use the following code:

```
if($obj->varify_user($key, $user_key)){
      //this is correct, you can proceed with  
    }
```

That's all.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out, you should not be storing your users' passwords in a format that is decryptable.  Reversable encryption provides an easy route for hackers to find out your users' passwords, which extends to putting your users' accounts at other sites at risk should they use the same password there.

PHP provides a pair of powerful functions for random-salted, one-way hash encryption — `password_hash()` and `password_verify()`.  Because the hash is automatically random-salted, there is no way for hackers to utilize precompiled tables of password hashes to reverse-engineer the password.  Set the `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` option and future versions of PHP will automatically use stronger algorithms to generate password hashes without you having to update your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`openssl_encrypt()`](http://php.net/openssl_encrypt) function.

Comment: Are the openssl encrypt in php 7 have the "heartbleed" ?

Comment: why should the OP use openssl_encrypt? Give some details and background

Answer (score 0):

I was able to translate my Crypto object

- Get a copy of php with mcrypt to decrypt the old data.  I went to http://php.net/get/php-7.1.12.tar.gz/from/a/mirror, compiled it, then added the ext/mcrypt extension (configure;make;make install). I think I had to add the extenstion=mcrypt.so line to the php.ini as well.  A series of scripts to build intermediate versions of the data with all data unencrypted.
- Build a public and private key for openssl

  ```
  openssl genrsa -des3 -out pkey.pem 2048
  (set a password)
  openssl rsa -in pkey.pem -out pkey-pub.pem -outform PEM -pubout
  ```
- To Encrypt (using public key) use openssl_seal. From what I've read, openssl_encrypt using an RSA key is limited to 11 bytes less than the key length (See http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php comment by Thomas Horsten)

  ```
  $pubKey = openssl_get_publickey(file_get_contents('./pkey-pub.pem'));
  openssl_seal($pwd, $sealed, $ekeys, [ $pubKey ]);
  $encryptedPassword = base64_encode($sealed);
  $key = base64_encode($ekeys[0]);
  ```

You could probably store the raw binary.

- To Decrypt (using private key)

  ```
  $passphrase="passphrase here";
  $privKey = openssl_get_privatekey(file_get_contents('./pkey.pem'), $passphrase);
  // I base64_decode() from my db columns
  openssl_open($encryptedPassword, $plain, $key, $privKey);
  echo "<h3>Password=$plain</h3>";
  ```

P.S. You can't encrypt the empty string ("")

P.P.S. This is for a password database not for user validation.