# PHP7.1 mcrypt alternative

Tags: php, encoding, decode, mcrypt, php-7.1

Mcrypt function has been deprecated as of PHP 7.1.0.

My deprecated string encode / decode functions:

```
$key: secret key
$str: string


$encoded = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $str, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));

$decoded = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), base64_decode($str), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "\0");
```

Can you suggest some alternatives?

Comment: You're out out of luck here. You're using a Rijndael-256 cipher, which is very unusual and not supported by OpenSSL. What you probably meant is AES-256, which is Rijndael-128 with a 256 bit key. If switching ciphers is an option for you, switch to Rijndael-128, in which case you can use OpenSSL.

Comment: why not just use sha-256 *(sha version 2)*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mcrypt is deprecated, what is the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272257/mcrypt-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should use [openssl_encrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) instead.

Comment: Encrypt example: http://micmap.org/php-by-example/en/function/openssl_encrypt  ,  Decrypt example: http://micmap.org/php-by-example/en/function/openssl_decrypt

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution, are being maintained and is correct.

Answer (score 1):

For `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` I posted a full answer for PHP7.3 here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53937314/243782

snippet:

works like this with the [phpseclib](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib) library

```
$rijndael = new \phpseclib\Crypt\Rijndael(\phpseclib\Crypt\Rijndael::MODE_ECB);
$rijndael->setKey(ENCRYPT_KEY);
$rijndael->setKeyLength(256);
$rijndael->disablePadding();
$rijndael->setBlockLength(256);

$decoded = $rijndael->decrypt($term);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo encrypt_openssl($str, $key);

function encrypt_openssl($msg, $key, $iv = null) {
        $iv_size = openssl_cipher_iv_length('AES-256-CBC');
        if (!$iv) {
            $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($iv_size);
        }
        $encryptedMessage = openssl_encrypt($msg, 'AES-256-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
        return base64_encode($iv . $encryptedMessage);
    }
```

**mcrypt** may be removed in PHP 7.1  alternative **openssl**

Answer (score -2):

As mentioned above, open_ssl is a good alternative for mcrypt. 
The only problem I had with open_ssl, is that it cannot be used for large strings.

I wrote a script (static class), which overcomes this problem (large strings are split up in chunks and encrypted/decrypted separately in the background).

See public gist:
https://gist.github.com/petermuller71/33616d55174d9725fc00a663d30194ba