# mcrypt_get_block_size(): Module initialization failed - Error on function

Tags: php, mcrypt

I am trying to create a function which can encrypt a string. I have the following code but I am getting an error.

`$key = "testkey";
    // This is the function that does the encryption. Treat it as a black box. Do not edit!
    function encrypt($str, $key){
     $block = mcrypt_get_block_size('ISO-8859-1', 'ecb');
     $pad = $block - (strlen($str) % $block);
     $str .= str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
     return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $str, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));
    }
    // call the encrypt function and send it the key and the data to encrypt. Store the returned data in the $dataopt variable.
    $dataopt = encrypt($rawstring, $key);`

The error is "mcrypt_get_block_size(): Module initialization failed on line on line 41" which is $block = mcrypt_get_block_size('ISO-8859-1', 'ecb');

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `'ISO-8859-1'` as the first parameter to `mcrypt_get_block_size`.

You probably meant to pass `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` as the first parameter.

Please note that mcrypt has been deprecated so you should probably look into other solutions.  Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41740600/php7-1-mcrypt-alternative) for some alternatives.

Comment: Hi Oz. Thanks for reply. I have replaced `ISO-8859-1` with MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 but I get the error "Warning: mcrypt_encrypt(): Key of size 7 not supported by this algorithm. Only keys of sizes 16, 24 or 32 supported in" on line 44 which relates to return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $str, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB)); Thanks for your help

Comment: @deanhodges if the answer helped, please accept it.  As I mentioned, I strongly suggest that you don't use `mcrypt` at all.  Your error is that you need a binary key and you're passing in a string (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php).  mcrypt is very low level and its easy to get things conceptually wrong **even if everything looks fine**.  I don't know why you're specifically trying to encrypt strings but there a better solution than mcrypt out there for almost any need.