# About a function has been deprecated for php

Tags: php

the php function `mcrypt_get_block_size` has been deprecated of PHP 7.1.0.

[PHP: mcrypt_get_block_size - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-get-block-size.php)

**Any hints on how I prevent that ?**

Comment: Prevent the function from being deprecated? Not possible I guess

Answer (score 0):

Deprecations to functions in PHP occur between versions - this is a good thing. One cannot actually **prevent** deprecation (without contributing to the project).

However, one can suppress the warnings that these deprecated functions throw. Of course, it is always better to update and refactor your code, but I think we're all aware that sometimes that might not be a possibility.

To suppress the warnings, one can edit their `php.ini` configuration file's `error_reporting` value to `E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE`. This will show all errors with the exception of deprecation warnings, and notices.

If it's only one script that you need to suppress, you can add the line `error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE);` at the top of the script. This will have the same effect, without affecting all PHP scripts in your environment.

A final, third option is to avoid using PHP versions >= 7.1.0, although one may also consider this a poor solution compared to refactoring the code.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at other mcrypt-related questions, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41740600/php7-1-mcrypt-alternative), it seems that there are openssl_* function alternatives?

See [openssl_cipher_iv_length()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-cipher-iv-length.php), as a possible replacement?