# Function mcrypt_create_iv() is deprecated within CodeIgniter framework

Tags: php, codeigniter, php-7.1

```
<?php 
class Encryption {
    var $skey     = "1234561234561234"; // you can change it

    public  function safe_b64encode($string) {

        $data = base64_encode($string);
        $data = str_replace(array('+','/','='),array('-','_',''),$data);
        return $data;
    }

    public function safe_b64decode($string) {
        $data = str_replace(array('-','_'),array('+','/'),$string);
        $mod4 = strlen($data) % 4;
        if ($mod4) {
            $data .= substr('====', $mod4);
        }
        return base64_decode($data);
    }

    public  function encode($value){ 

        if(!$value){return false;}
        $text = $value;
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        $crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->skey, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
        return trim($this->safe_b64encode($crypttext)); 
    }

    public function decode($value){

        if(!$value){return false;}
        $crypttext = $this->safe_b64decode($value); 
        $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
        $decrypttext = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->skey, $crypttext, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
        return trim($decrypttext);
    }

}
```

It's my `encryption.php` file. I tried to solve this error and research lots of time but i could not find proper answer. I am newer in PHP.

Error :

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: 8192
>
> Message: Function mcrypt_create_iv() is deprecated
>
> Filename: libraries/Encryption.php
>
> Line Number: 27

Comment: what's the php version installed and used on the server?

Comment: i am currently using php  version: 7.1.4

Comment: that's the problem then. Look at the manual and what it states http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-create-iv.php

Comment: I use [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php) It works in php7

Comment: APIs change - to avoid breaking existing code normally a method is deprecated with warning, then deprecated with error, then removed. just fix your code to use whatever replaced the deprecated piece of the API.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-create-iv.php states:

> **Warning**
>
> This function was DEPRECATED in PHP 7.1.0, and REMOVED in PHP 7.2.0.
>
> Alternatives to this function include:
>
> - [random_bytes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php)

There is an alternate solution if you don't want to use [`random_bytes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php), and it is shown here:

- [PHP 7 - mcrypt deprecated, need alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272257/php-7-mcrypt-deprecated-need-alternative)