# PHP 7.2 MCRYPT_BLOWFISH replacement?

Tags: php, php-7.2

I’m using

```
mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_BLOWFISH...
```

I’ve upgraded to PHP 7.2 and mcrypt is now removed.  Is there a drop in replacement?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272257/php-7-mcrypt-deprecated-need-alternative

Comment: I don’t think this is a duplicate since I was asking specifically about the MCRYPT_BLOWFISH algorithm.  Note my answer has the details to replace this, not another algorithm.

Comment: @JoshPetitt True. I edited that one out and replaced them with two other ones. A Google search for "alternative to mcrypt_decrypt php 7" produced both of those.

Comment: @Sammitch Please read the question carefully before choosing a duplicate. I had to edit it. See my above to Josh.

Comment: I wasn't marking as a dupe, I posted the link as its relevant since the accepted answer mentions libsodium and Defuse Which I believe are the PHP 7+ alternatives to mcrypt.

Comment: @DaveCarruthers We weren't questioning yours Dave, but the one that Sammitch chose as the duplicate originally used to hammer the question. Your link however was a good one though.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work

```
openssl_decrypt($data, 'BF-ECB', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_NO_PADDING)
```

Comment: `‘BF-ECB’` - Actually, those curly quotes will produce a parse error. They should be regular quotes `'BF-ECB'`, *just saying* and for future visitors to the question/answer.

Comment: Sorry I typed on my phone, feel free to update, or I will tonight

Comment: No worries Josh; I edited it.