# m_crypt() is deprecated in PHP 7.2

Tags: php, laravel

I am working with a client that uses an API that's expecting encrypted data in a particular format, having moved to Laravel and upgraded to PHP 7.2, I attempted to use the encryption function that they had provided.

```
<?php
class Encrypt {
    public function encryptData ($data)
    {
        //16
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_RAND);
        $hash = $this->getEncryptionKey();
        //Using PKCS7 padding
        $encrypted = openssl_encrypt($data, 'AES-128-CBC', $hash, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
        echo "\niv:\n"; echo base64_encode($iv) ;
        echo "\nencrypted:\n" ;echo base64_encode($encrypted) ;
        //echo "iv:" + base64_encode($iv) + "\n";
        //echo "encrypted:" + base64_encode($encrypted); + "\n";
        return ['iv' => base64_encode($iv), 'ct' => base64_encode($encrypted)];
    }
    private function getEncryptionKey ()
    {
        //update the password and salt with yours
        $password = "somepassword=";
        $salt = 'somesalt';
        $iterations = 1000;
        $keySize = 128;
        $blockSize = 128;
        return hash_pbkdf2("sha1", $password, $salt, $iterations, $keySize / 8, true);
    }
}
?>
```

However, it seems `mcrypt()` has been deprecated as of PHP 7.2, is there an alternative?

Comment: Instead of using `sha1` consider using [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

Comment: I posted a full answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/53937314/243782