# Error when trying to install PHP on Ubuntu 18.04 for AWS EC2

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I am busy setting up my ec2 for my website. I am using the Ubuntu 18.04 AMI(Amazon Machine Image).I need to run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0 php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-mysql mysql-server 
apache2
```

But when I try to execute the installation I receive these errors:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'php7.0-remctl' for regex 'php7.0'
Note, selecting 'php7.0-common' for regex 'php7.0'
Note, selecting 'php-remctl' instead of 'php7.0-remctl'
E: Unable to locate package libapache2-mod-php7.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libapache2-mod-php7.0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libapache2-mod-php7.0'
E: Unable to locate package php7.0-mysql
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.0-mysql'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.0-mysql'
```

I am running these commands through MobaXterm on Windows 10. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP 7.0 is obsolete -- [it reached end-of-life in January 2019](https://php.net/eol.php) -- and it is not available in Ubuntu 18.04. The appropriate version for this release is PHP 7.2 (e.g. [`php7.2`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/php7.2), [`php7.2-mysql`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/php7.2-mysql), etc); you will need to change your install commands accordingly.

The mcrypt extension [was deprecated in PHP 7.1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.deprecated.php) and subsequently [removed in PHP 7.2](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration72.other-changes.php). If you are using this extension in your application, [you will need to rework those parts of your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272257/mcrypt-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative).