# how to decrypt string encrypted with mcrypt_encrypt using MCRYPT_DES and ecb

Tags: php, laravel-5.8, php-7.3

I am in a situation where I have to decrypt a string coming from a cookie which is already encrypted using mcrypt_encrypt method on an old system using php 5.6 (which I cannot change for now) while I am using php 7.3 which does not support this, is there any alternate or workaround to solve this

old system uses this method to encrypt which for some reason I cannot change `mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_DES, $this->salt, serialize($arrayData), 'ecb');`

I have tried openssl_decrypt but it returns false with following
`openssl_decrypt($encryptedString, 'DES-ECB', $this->salt) OR openssl_decrypt($encryptedString, 'des-ecb', $this->salt)`

Comment: PHP 7.3 does support mcrypt but as [a separate pecl package](https://pecl.php.net/package/mcrypt) for use if you have a legacy need such as yours. Ideally you'd only use this to deprecate and remove legacy encryption support and not as a way to keep using mcrypt forever

Comment: This is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272257/mcrypt-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative/41272680

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mcrypt is deprecated, what is the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272257/mcrypt-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative)

Comment: thanks @apokryfos I will try that out and yes you right I will be using it to deprecate this.

Comment: the other answers does not cater this specific need as those recommend alternate methods for both encryption and decryption while my specific need is to convert already encrypted keys with above mentioned code

Comment: @apokryfos I have installed the pecl package and it is enabled too but when I use the function mcrypt_decrypt it throws following exception `Function mcrypt_decrypt() is deprecated` I am using it in laravel 5.8

Comment: You can do `$errorReporting = error_reporting(); error_reporting($errorReporting & ~E_DEPRECATED);` to stop treating deprecation warnings are reportable errors and then restore the old setting using `error_reporting($errorReporting);` when you're done using mcrypt functions.

Comment: thanks, it worked when muted warning, I have used @ symbol with method name to mute the warning