# Decrypt string that is encrypted by MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128

Tags: php, encryption, php-openssl

I used following codes to encrypt and decrypt the strings in php. I recently upgraded my server and now i can see that the codes i use is depreciated. Encryption code is **hardcoded on my app** so i need to decrypt on the server. Please provide the alternative to both encrypt and decrypt

Code for encryption.

```
function encrypt($data = '', $key = 'chiperbase65enus')
    {
    $encrypted = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, 'chiperbase65enus');
        return base64_encode($encrypted);
    }
```

And for decryption is below. I dont actually need encryption anymore but decryption is the must.

```
function decrypt($data = '', $key = 'chiperbase65enus')
    {
        $decrypted = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, base64_decode($data), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,'chiperbase65enus');
        return rtrim($decrypted, "\0");
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mcrypt is deprecated, what is the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272257/mcrypt-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative)

Answer (score 1):

```
 $decrypted = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($encrypted_string), "AES-128-CBC", "chiperbase65enus",OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, "chiperbase65enus");
```

I found the solution...