# mcrypt is not installed with the php 5.6

Tags: php, mcrypt

I have installed the php version 5.6 and in order to run my laravel application it is asking to install and enable the mcrypt extension. These are the steps I followed.

```
brew install php56 php56-mcrypt
nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

Then editing the httpd.conf file I added the following.

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/local/opt/php56/libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
```

But when I run the following command in order to check the "mcrypt" availability still it shows that it is not installed.

```
php -i | grep "mcrypt"
```

Comment: Why are you using PHP 5.6?

Comment: The existing project needs php 5.6

Comment: Did you add the `extension=/where/ever/php/extensions/are/installed/mcrypt.so` to the `php.ini` file?

Comment: I would strongly recommend to upgrade to a supported PHP version. Mcrypt has been removed from PHP already. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/41272257/1839439

Comment: Just because I think the point needs emphasising - **PHP 5.6 is dead**. It has been out of active support for nearly 3 years and security patches stopped almost a year ago (Debian notwithstanding) - you **really** should upgrade.

Comment: https://www.php.net/eol.php

Comment: Anyway this issue have been sorted since I have used another ubuntu PC for this thing. Thanks for the support guys.

Comment: I do have the same issue. and still need php 5.6

Answer (score 0):

I made it working on mac or windows using the Xampp that uses php 5.6 and my issue with the mcrypt is gone.

Comment: I am shocked seeing my own answer 1 year ago while recalling how I did it.