# How to get complete decryption when using phpseclib (php 7) to replace deprecated MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL (php 5)?

Tags: php, encryption, phpseclib

I have to upgrade a script from php 5.6 to 7.4, but I need to decrypt data previosly encrypted with `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` (deprecated). I try to use [phpseclib - Github](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib) (based on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272257/mcrypt-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative/53937314#53937314)), but I'm getting an incomplete result (strange chars). How can I get the correct decrtypted data?

For example:

```
$key = "0123456789abcdefghijklmn"; // len = 24
$data = "ABC123 abc123 ABC123 abc123 ABC123 abc123 ABC123 abc123";
```

PHP 5.6 encryption:

```
$enc_old = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));
echo $enc_old;
// eOIZd9ND59vfjx6A5fteiFQWgwYFawPccCieAxD1Ir+xJnutpdsc7b6ELNArNPLSghfdVteO0WM4lcfTQToR8w==
```

PHP 5.6 decryption => OK:

```
$dec_old = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), base64_decode($enc_old), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "\0");

echo $dec_old;
// ABC123 abc123 ABC123 abc123 ABC123 abc123 ABC123 abc123
```

PHP 7.4 decryption with `phpseclib`:

```
require "vendor/autoload.php";

$rijndael = new \phpseclib\Crypt\Rijndael(\phpseclib\Crypt\Rijndael::MODE_CBC);
$rijndael->setKey( md5($key) );
$rijndael->setKeyLength(256);
$rijndael->disablePadding();
$rijndael->setBlockLength(256);

$dec_new = $rijndael->decrypt( base64_decode($enc_old) );

echo $dec_new;
// ttRFXQZVr {PFTVTPs t23 abc123 ABC123 abc123
```

Basically, the first part of the data seems corrupted. But the rest of the data is ok.
How can I decrypt the entire data correctly?

**EDIT**:
As pointed out by @Michael Fehr , in the original `mcrypt_encrypt` version an `IV` was set (i.e. [the last parameter](https://www.php.net/manual/ro/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php): `md5(md5($key)`) ), that had to be added in the decryption. Thus, I added this line:

```
$rijndael->setIV( md5(md5($key)) );
```

and now the entire data *is decrypted correctly*.

Comment: Using "old" PHP 5.6 you hash the $key two times with md5 for the value of initialization vector, the "new" 7.4 decryption does not set the IV ?

Comment: Thank you! I added this line: <code>$rijndael->setIV( md5(md5($key)) );</code> and now the decryption is full. I will test it on a long real-data file, to see if that makes it right. Could you post it as an answer with some explanation why that changes everything? To select it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your PHP 5.6 encryption you code:

```
$enc_old = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));
```

where the last md5(md5($key)) is for the initialization vector.

I'm missing the setting of the IV in your (new) PHP 7.4 decryption method - as you are using AES in the mode CBC and that requires an IV.

As you found by yourself you should add the line

```
$rijndael->setIV( md5(md5($key)) );
```

to get your decryption working.