# Is mcrypt_encrypt() function not working in PHP 7.2?

Tags: php

I have encryption code as below & it was working in PHP version 5.6. But it is not working in PHP version 7.2.

**

> Warning : Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 - assumed
> 'MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128' (this will throw an Error in a future version of
> PHP)

**

Any alternative of this?

```
$serviceid="2951";
$secretkey = "fQ5FHy0qzM6ljp97";

function pkcs5_pad ($text, $blocksize)
{
  $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize);
  return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
}

function encrypt($plaintext, $key) {
    $plaintext = pkcs5_pad($plaintext, 16);
    $ciphertext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $plaintext, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $ciphertext_base64 = base64_encode($ciphertext);
    $ciphertext_base64; 
}
$data = $serviceid;
$auth= encrypt($data ,$secretkey);
```

Value of encryption is **AGchNk2xOnHHxhgYv02XJw==**

I tried with below code in PHP 7.2

```
function encrypt($plaintext, $key) 
{
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-128-cbc'));
$encrypted = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, 'aes-128-cbc', $key, 0, $iv);
return base64_encode($encrypted . '::' . $iv);
}
```

but output keeps changing

Comment: Define "not working". Do you get any errors, warnings or notices? Or unexpected results?

Comment: Anyways, a quick look at the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt) should clear the issue.

Comment: @El_Vanja I added warning in question. Warning : Use of undefined constant MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 - assumed 'MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128' (this will throw an Error
in a future version of PHP)

Comment: As already answered "mcrypt" was removed from PHP 7.2.x. As your mcrypt encryption uses AES (= Rijndael 128) the **ECB** mode you should use this with OpenSSL as well (so leave out all code regarding the "iv" (initialization vector).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found solution of my query. Please check below

```
function encrypt($plaintext,$key)
{
    return base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($plaintext, 'aes-128-ecb', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA));
}
```

Comment: _Is mcrypt_encrypt() function not working in PHP 7.2?_ The real answer was **NO** as mine.

Answer (score 3):

As you can see into [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php)  `mcrypt_encrypt` is **REMOVED** from PHP 7.2.0

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272257/mcrypt-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative) an SO question for best alternative

Comment: Is this okay?

function encrypt($plaintext, $key) 
{
$iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-128-cbc'));
$encrypted = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, 'aes-128-cbc', $key, 0, $iv);
return base64_encode($encrypted . '::' . $iv);
}