# AES encrypt PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.3

Tags: php, encryption, aes

I would like to transform the code below code **PHP 5.6** to **PHP 7.3**, We are more grateful to that person who provides us some suggestions on learning encryption in PHP on a more detailed level so we can try to convert that code itself.

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10)
{
    
    $characters       = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString     = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
    {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    
    return $randomString;
}

function strToHex($string)
{
    
    $hex = '';
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++)
    {
        $ord     = ord($string[$i]);
        $hexCode = dechex($ord);
        $hex     .= substr('0' . $hexCode, -2);
    }
    
    return strToUpper($hex);
}

function AESencrypt($decrypted, $password = 'password', $salt = 'salt_key')
{
    
    $block     = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
    $padding   = $block - (strlen($decrypted) % $block);
    $decrypted .= str_repeat(chr($padding), $padding);
    $encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $password, $decrypted, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $password));
    $encrypted = hash('SHA256', $encrypted . '|' . $salt, true);
    
    return strToHex($encrypted);
}

$agentid   = "EU01EU22INB000";
$mercode   = "BPP";
$username  = "BPP_01";
$userpass  = "BPP_01";
$storecode = "BPP_01";
$ipaddr    = "103.235.104.168";
$billerid    = '00000NATTQ';
$bbpstel     = 'QH01WD3737';
$bbpstel1    = $bbpstel;
$stringParts = str_split($bbpstel1);
sort($stringParts);
$sortval = implode('', $stringParts);
$sort = $sortval;
$Billfetch = "BillPay" . generateRandomString();

$hashkey   = AESencrypt($Billfetch . "|" . $mercode . "|" . $agentid . "|" . $billerid . "|" . $sort, "password", "salt_key");
echo $Billfetch."----".$hashkey."<br/>";
exit;
```

Comment: Above mentioned parameter in the variable, it's for example only, which is now the right data.

Comment: If you are looking for possible alternatives to the deprecated _mcrypt_, this question has already been answered here: [mcrypt is deprecated, what is the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272257/mcrypt-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative)