# How to convert mcrypt_encrypt into openssl_encrypt?

Tags: php, openssl, mcrypt

I wanted to improve a certain wordpress plugin that uses the now obsolete "mcrypt". Instead of it, I would like to use the OpenSSL library to encrypt the submited data, but during the encryption I ran into problems, namely: the openssl_encrypt function returns a different value than mcrypt_encrypt by which the system I am connecting to does not return me the correct data, and its owner has no way to send me logs of what I uploaded to it :(

I've already scoured the internet the length and breadth of the Internet, but have not found a solution. I suspect that the problem is padding, but I can't find a solution. Can you help?

Below are the insides of my PHP object $password, $salt and $iv are obviously changed

```
class EncryptDebug{
private $algo = 'sha1';
private $password = 'ab4232goodcf423484422c90c3e4aa7c';
private $salt = 'ascastas54490a31';
private $iv = '8947da32awl55kwj'
private $lenght = 16;
private function generate_key(){
    return hash_pbkdf2( $this->algo , $this->password , $this->salt, 100, $this->lenght, true );
}
public function encryptSSL($plaintext){
    $key = $this->generate_key();
    $ciphertext = base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($plaintext, 'AES-128-CBC', $key,  OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $this->iv));
    
    return str_replace('+', '%2B', $ciphertext);

}
public function encryptMCRYPT($plaintext){
    $key = $this->generate_key();
    $ciphertext = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $plaintext, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $this->iv));
    
    return str_replace('+', '%2B', $ciphertext);

}
}
```

Forgot to mention: OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING returns error. Using OPENSSL_RAW_DATA I'm able to get results similar to mcrypt_encrypt, but the ending is different, example:

OpenSSL: rPzVvF7gaPMA4ADAjHUW8Wy1ThTJG%2BVPdcz5iKAkAwrDTTFTcOpWgWOCh9l9JFZ8WcNzMJ868026TkUxcYJMrQ==

MCRYPT: rPzVvF7gaPMA4ADAjHUW8Wy1ThTJG%2BVPdcz5iKAkAwrDTTFTcOpWgWOCh9l9JFZ8UGVfF091Q9bY61mTRg%2BBSg==

Comment: Forgot to mention: OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING returns error. Using OPENSSL_RAW_DATA I'm able to get results similar to mcrypt_encrypt, but the ending is different, example:
OpenSSL: rPzVvF7gaPMA4ADAjHUW8Wy1ThTJG%2BVPdcz5iKAkAwrDTTFTcOpWgWOCh9l9JFZ8WcNzMJ868026TkUxcYJMrQ==
MCRYPT: rPzVvF7gaPMA4ADAjHUW8Wy1ThTJG%2BVPdcz5iKAkAwrDTTFTcOpWgWOCh9l9JFZ8UGVfF091Q9bY61mTRg%2BBSg==

Comment: The posted code is not executable. Post an executable code (see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). Also post your PHP/OpenSSL code with test data. There are quite a few posts on SO about converting mcrypt -> openssl, e.g. [mcrypt is deprecated, what is the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41272257/9014097). Check if your problem can't be solved with it.

Comment: Also please do not add additional information in comments here. There is an "edit" link below your question. _Use it ..._

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comments. I've edited my post. 

Also yes, I've made a research before I've posted this. I couldn't find a way to make my code work. Posting on stackoverflow is my last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `encryptSSL()` it is currently Base64 encoded twice, once explicitly, once implicitly by default. One of the Base64 encodings must therefore be removed, either the explicit or the implicit one. The former is achieved by removing the `base64_encode()` call, the latter by setting the `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` flag.

In addition, *mcrypt* uses Zero padding and *PHP/OpenSSL* uses PKCS#7 padding. Therefore, so that `encryptSSL()` gives the same result as `encryptMCRYPT()`, Zero padding must be used. Since *PHP/OpenSSL* does not support Zero padding, PKCS#7 padding must be disabled (with the `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING` flag) and Zero padding must be implemented *explicitly*.

Overall:

```php
$ciphertext = openssl_encrypt($this->zeroPad($plaintext, 16), 'AES-128-CBC', $key,  OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $this->iv); // remove base64_encode(), zero pad plaintext, disable PKCS#7 padding
```

with:

```php
protected function zeroPad($text, $bs) {
    $pad = $bs - strlen($text) % $bs;
    return ($pad < 16) ? $text .  str_repeat("\0", $pad) : $text;
}
```

With these changes, both functions give the same result.

Be aware, that Zero padding is unreliable compared to PKCS#7 padding.

---

Security:

Note that a static IV and a static salt are vulnerabilities. Instead, both are to be randomly generated and passed to the decrypting side along with the ciphertext, typically concatenated (both are not secret).

Furthermore, an iteration count of 100 for PBKDF2 is usually far too small.

Comment: Thanks! It worked! Thanks for directing me, now everything works as it should and I'm better at working on this code! You don't even know how much you helped me. 
Thanks for taking the time to reply :)