# How can I replace mcrypt's encryption of MCRYPT_DES with openssl?

Tags: openssl

I want to upgrade LEMP to php8.2, but it's difficult to install the deprecated mcyrpt environment for php in the docker environment. Since the original code uses mcyrpt to encrypt data, I hope to upgrade the encryption function to openssl while maintaining compatibility with the previously encrypted data. Although I have made many attempts, I have not succeeded due to my lack of familiarity with encryption functions. I hope to get your help.

```
<?php
const MY_PRJ='v26a2';
const My_PRJ_NUM=765432;
class CryptDes {
    function __construct(){
        $mykey=MY_PRJ;
        $myiv= My_PRJ_NUM ;
        $this->key = $mykey;
        $this->iv =$myiv;
    }
    /*
     * encryption
     */
    function encrypt($input){
        $size = mcrypt_get_block_size(MCRYPT_DES,MCRYPT_MODE_CBC);
        $input = $this->pkcs5_pad($input, $size);
        $key = str_pad($this->key,8,'0');
        $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_DES, '', MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, '');
        if( $this->iv == '' )
        {
            $iv = @mcrypt_create_iv (mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND);
        }
        else
        {
            $iv = $this->iv;
        }
        @mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
        $data = mcrypt_generic($td, $input);
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
        mcrypt_module_close($td);
        $data = bin2hex($data);
        return $data;
    }
    /*
     * decrypt
     */
    function decrypt($encrypted){
        $encrypted =@hex2bin($encrypted);
        $key = str_pad($this->key,8,'0');
        $td = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_DES,'',MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,'');
        if( $this->iv == '' )
        {
            $iv = @mcrypt_create_iv (mcrypt_enc_get_iv_size($td), MCRYPT_RAND);
        }
        else
        {
            $iv = $this->iv;
        }
        $ks = mcrypt_enc_get_key_size($td);
        @mcrypt_generic_init($td, $key, $iv);
        $decrypted = @mdecrypt_generic($td, $encrypted);
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
        mcrypt_module_close($td);
        $y=$this->pkcs5_unpad($decrypted);
        return $y;
    }
    function pkcs5_pad ($text, $blocksize) {
        $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize);
        return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
    }
    function pkcs5_unpad($text){
        $pad = ord($text[strlen($text)-1]);
        if ($pad > strlen($text)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (strspn($text, chr($pad), strlen($text) - $pad) != $pad){
            return false;
        }
        return substr($text, 0, -1 * $pad);
    }
}

/*
 * test
 */
$des = new CryptDes();
$do_ps = function ($str) use ($des) {
    return $des->encrypt($str);
};
$un_ps = function ($mres) use ($des) {
    return $des->decrypt($mres);
};

echo $do_ps("test") . '<br>';
echo $un_ps($do_ps("test")) .'<br>';`
```

Comment: See [mcrypt is deprecated, what is the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272257/mcrypt-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative). If that is not enough, you should post your most recent PHP/OpenSSL code and describe the problem, SO is not a code delivery service. I also recommend using appropriate tags to reach a wider audience. Be aware that DES has been retired for about 20 years, you should consider a new algorithm. The current standard is AES.