# salt and hash encryption/decryption for links

Tags: php, hash, salt, saltedhash

ok, so i have some links that will be generated for some ads on my website via php. Now the problem i have is simply i understand how md5 works and it's not an encryption and it can not be re-rendered in its rarest form..... i have some mysql ids that i want to use as the data to  select witch ad to query the database for , but i do not want my users to have access to the ads id..... so i was hoping someone could show me how to use the hash/salt method in this case.....
Please note: i have been looking through this site for this answer and i see people time and time again say salt/hash is not encryption i understand that but its not as simple to attempt to hack my site if the links were hashed as they would be if they were just simple integers.

php script:

```
<?
function SuperAd($id){
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `ads` WHERE `id`= $id");
    while($ad = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $title = $ad['title'];
        // here is where i want to encrypt 
        $adlink = $ad['id'];
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Your question is not at all clear.  What it is that you want to perform the hash on?  And when?

Comment: I don't understand how an attacker could hack your site just by knowing the ad id?

Comment: @xqus It's easy, actually: just use an id of `1; drop ...` ^^

Comment: @pst: Not sure if serious... *checks reputation* hmmz...

Comment: @pst True. How could i miss that one ;)

Comment: I think you are simply looking for a unique, random id for each ad, not necessary for *encrypting* a numeric id.

Comment: @josh this is the main reason im starting to dislike stack .... if you dont have nothing nice to say then dont say nothing at all. obviously i don't know or i wouldn't ask a question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding salt is just a securer addition to hashing. And hashing is one way only. It sounds like you want some way of encrypting your `$ad['id']`, so that instead of users seeing:

`/viewad/1/`

they see:

`/viewad/12lk3jx09c8faf/`

right?

Just Google for some quick encryption / decryption algorithms.

*EDIT*: Here is a quick S.O. question that may help you:

[Best way to use PHP to encrypt and decrypt passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1289061/420001)

Comment: Although there is not an inherent reason to use encryption... there are numerous ways to map external values to an internal ID... the methods that used a nonce *could* actually be potentially "more secure" than encryption.

Comment: I agree. Two way encryption seems like a better choice. If not you also need to store the hash in the db, and then.. you could just used the id.

Answer (score 1):

You could solve your problem by using a row guid which would be unique & non guessable without having to do a hash