# sanitizing a string before serializing and inserting to db

Tags: php

I'm facing an odd problem....

`$string` is user input

```
$log = serialize(array('string' => $string);
```

example: "test" would be

> "string";s:4:"test";

However problems arise when the user submits quotes and some other characters like ;
Of course I escape the string first, but the serialized data cannot be unserialized.

`htmlentities` before submitting to db wouldn't work either since `;` messes up the data...

Any suggestions?

Please don't tell me to create db fields and not use `serialize()`

Comment: Erm: "problems arise when the user submits quotes and some other characters like ; " => no they don't, try it.

Comment: "sanitizing" for a database depends ENTIERLY on whatever database and database interface library you're using. E.g. suggesting to use mysql_real_escape_string() would be pointless if you're using Postgres.  And would also be entirely redundant if you're using PDO. As well, using htmlentitiees for DB sanitization is the equivalent of using gasoline for putting out a fire.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the best practice but a quick hack would be using : http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php to encrypt the data when sending it to DB and then decrypting it when you retrieve it. now if you think there might be a security issues encrypting using base64 here is a link to do it in a better way : 
[Best way to use PHP to encrypt and decrypt passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289061/best-way-to-use-php-to-encrypt-and-decrypt)

Comment: Excellent idea, thank you. I don't see what security issues could there be, as it's not sensitive data being transferred. encode - escape - db - decode - htmlentitles.

Comment: Base64 is encoding, not encryption. Anyone can decode Base64 using terminals, programming languages, online tools...

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape user input before inserting it to the database not only because it can break your application but because it is a *serious security vulnerability* if you don't do so.

Please read this article: http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/3.html#3.2

I strongly suggest using [PDO with prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) in your application, or implementing an abstraction over escaping and using it always in your application (for example with `mysqli_real_escape_string`).