# How do I pass a string containing / round in a URL?

Tags: php, encoding

I've been looking at [this encryption method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289061/best-way-to-use-php-to-encrypt-and-decrypt), which uses base 64.

However, since base64 includes `/`, when I pass it via a URL the inclusion of `/` might mess things up. How do I get round this?

Comment: Use http://www.php.net/urlencode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That answer base 64 encodes it, and since base 64 includes `/`, you'll want to encode it again, for which you can use [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php). When you have a `urlencode`d string, you can get its value with [`urldecode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php).

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1. you could [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the encrypted code
2. or you could access `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`