# encrypt a part of source code

Tags: php, encryption

I have a php file. I just want to protect a few line in it. So I need to encrypt file but I still want it works like a normal php file. Which software/tool should I use now? Can you give me an advice.

I want something like this

```
<?php
... 
normal code
...
encrypted code (Dfhjkllasjdoasd)
...
normal code
?>
```

Thank you

Comment: How/When do you intend to use the encrypted code? You'll always need to decrypt it in order to use it. In general, attempting to encrypt the text in script-based files is a waste of time.

Comment: Why would you want to partially encrypt a file? Just put the piece of code you want to "protect" in a different file and encrypt that as a whole.

Comment: What's the use case? Most things like this can be bypassed with enough effort, and it only needs one person to do so and share the code for the whole exercise to be pointless.

Comment: I want to protect license checking code that I include in a file. If user remove it, they will share script for free, it called Nulled :(

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using IonCube, PhpSheild, SourceGuardian.

Looking for free? its can be build into php. check [bCompiler](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bcompiler.php)

Please note, that these encoded/encrypted file can be included in other files too, so you can have some of your files encoded/encrypted and leave which you don't want to.

for Partial textual encryption & decryption see [Best way to use PHP to encrypt and decrypt passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289061/best-way-to-use-php-to-encrypt-and-decrypt)

Comment: I have zend guard, do you know how to encrypt apart of code only?

Comment: you can consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289061/best-way-to-use-php-to-encrypt-and-decrypt for part encryptions.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider moving the important bits into a separate file as functions and compiling them into a PHP extension using something like [HipHop](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php). It would increase the hassle of installing your software though, so you need to be sure it's worth it.

Comment: HipHop doesn't works on windows. for creating php extensions, you don't use hipHop. HipHop is for compiling PHP scripts into executables.