# Two way encryption in php

Tags: php, security, encryption, cryptography, encryption-symmetric

I need to do a 2-way encryption in PHP. Basically what I want to do is convert a string(`Marshall` for example) to something weird(`s2323sdavrt44` for example) and then convert that (`s2323sdavrt44`) back to clear text string(`Marshall`).

How can I achieve this? And no I'm not doing this for passwords or anything, for div id attribute, so later I can split it for SQL queries.

Comment: split it for what? SQL queries?

Comment: I.... didn't understand what's the point of it all. There might be a [better solution](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$key = 'password to (en/de)crypt';
$string = 'string to be encrypted';

$encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));
$decrypted = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), base64_decode($encrypted), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "\0");

var_dump($encrypted);
var_dump($decrypted);
```

Comment: For future reference: using mcrypt is a bad idea. It has security holes and unpatched bugs and is even deprecated in PHP 7.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is using XOR encryption [<sup>wikipedia</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher). In this case you will have to use a "key" to encode and decode the text.

There is an example [<sup>php.net</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) for php, look at the example#2

Answer (score 0):

It is not in the php core but you can take a look at

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php
and http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php where you can crypt and decrypt strings with a valid key.

There is a good post about it at [Best way to use PHP to encrypt and decrypt passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289061/best-way-to-use-php-to-encrypt-and-decrypt)

Answer (score -1):

```
$string === str_rot13( str_rot13($string) );
```

Comment: unless you wanna use something like open ssl, which would be a total overkill here, nothing really is "encryption"

Comment: though he indeed says encryption in the question, i believe str_rot13 qualifies for "something weird"

Comment: True. For what OP seems to want rot13 would probably work, but it should be noted that it is not, in fact, encryption.

Comment: in fact, it is, it's just that the knowledge for decryption is readily available

Answer (score -2):

If u want to use any encryption then u can use 'openssl' in which u can use any reverseble encryptiopn algorithm to encrypt and decrypt. I have used this in php and works just fine.

All details are on this page : http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php