# Encryption of password to store into database

Tags: mysql, database, encryption, passwords

I am developing a web application using netbeans. I am using MySQL as my data base. I want to store the user password in encrypted form in table. and when I will access it using web application they should be in decrypted form. How can I achieve this ? Thanks

Comment: Why do you need it decrypted? Isn't a hash sufficent?

Comment: To comapre when user enters the password while login i need to check and compare it with it one that is data base. Ya hash will be enough but how to do that?

Comment: A little search here on SO or on google would have brought up this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289061/best-way-to-use-php-to-encrypt-and-decrypt

Comment: juergen d, that is a valid point, but perhaps his vocabulary doesn't yet include the word hash?=)

Comment: @adesh: Well, if you create a hash in PHP and compare it to the hash in the database, then this is perfect. Just to get you on the way: When adding a new user to the database, store the user name and a hash of the password. Then, when the user logs in, search for an entry in the database which matches the entered user name and the hash of the password that the user has entered. That way you don't need to store any passwords at all in your database.

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar  yup thanx for u quick response. I got your answer. I am also on same track but i dont how to produce hash in java . How can i generate hash of password?

Comment: @adesh: Again, a quick google for "Java create hash" brought up this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415953/generate-md5-hash-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Try this if hasing is enough

```
SELECT PASSWORD('mypass')
```