# Parsing user input via AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, xml, ajax

Now, this isn't a "debug my codez for me plz" question. I've spent... I don't even want to think how long on trying to fix this issue.

My problem is that I am executing this php page that is, ideally, examining a string and converting it to a more secure format since this page is to store passwords for accounts.

What I'm aiming at with this code below is to slice the string repeatedly at each character and then evaluate it to my key. It does this for the whole string length. What's been being returned to me is '0'. I don't know how the system is even getting this value.

Maybe I'm using the substr() function wrong? Also, I'm open to a completely different method of parsing the string, such as using a RegExp. Thank you for your help, guys!

Code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
#region Initial
$accstr = "apple";
$accn = "scourge";
//Key
$a[0] = "#"; //These variables are for conversion; indexes of this array correspond to those
$a[1] = "!"; //of the other array ($ind)
$a[2] = "@";
$a[3] = "%$";
$a[4] = "%";
$a[5] = "!@";
$a[6] = "&*";
$a[7] = "^";
$a[8] = "##";
$a[9] = "&^";
$a[10] = "&";
$a[11] = "%~";
$a[12] = "!%";
$a[13] = "!$";
$a[14] = "*#";
$a[15] = "#*";
$a[16] = "~";
$a[17] = "~&";
$a[18] = "``";
$a[19] = "/^";
$a[20] = "%`";
$a[21] = "~~";
$a[22] = "`~";
$a[23] = "%%";
$a[24] = "~!";
$a[25] = "~#";
$a[26] = "``#";
$a[27] = "``!";
$a[28] = "``@";
$a[29] = "``%$";
$a[30] = "``%";
$a[31] = "``!@";
$a[32] = "``&*";
$a[33] = "``^";
$a[34] = "``##";
$a[35] = "``&^";
$a[36] = "&&^#";
$a[37] = "~@!";
$a[38] = "!@&@";
$a[39] = "%~~$";
$a[40] = "%`%";
$a[41] = "!^~@";
$a[42] = "&#$*";
$a[43] = "^**&";
$a[44] = "#%#`";
$a[45] = "&``!@^";
$a[46] = "&**~&";
$a[47] = "%|~";
$a[48] = "!-|~%";
$a[49] = "!$~";
$a[50] = "*/#";
$a[51] = "#%*";
$a[52] = "|~";

$ind[0] = "a";//These are used to tell what's being looked at in the string
$ind[1] = "b";
$ind[2] = "c";
$ind[3] = "d";
$ind[4] = "e";
$ind[5] = "f";
$ind[6] = "g";
$ind[7] = "h";
$ind[8] = "i";
$ind[9] = "j";
$ind[10] = "k";
$ind[11] = "l";
$ind[12] = "m";
$ind[13] = "n";
$ind[14] = "o";
$ind[15] = "p";
$ind[16] = "q";
$ind[17] = "r";
$ind[18] = "s";
$ind[19] = "t";
$ind[20] = "u";
$ind[21] = "v";
$ind[22] = "w";
$ind[23] = "x";
$ind[24] = "y";
$ind[25] = "z";
$ind[26] = "0";
$ind[27] = "1";
$ind[28] = "2";
$ind[29] = "3";
$ind[30] = "4";
$ind[31] = "5";
$ind[32] = "6";
$ind[33] = "7";
$ind[34] = "8";
$ind[35] = "9";
$ind[36] = "~";
$ind[37] = "!";
$ind[38] = "@";
$ind[39] = "#";
$ind[40] = "$";
$ind[41] = "%";
$ind[42] = "^";
$ind[43] = "&";
$ind[44] = "*";
$ind[45] = "(";
$ind[46] = ")";
$ind[47] = "_";
$ind[48] = "+";
$ind[49] = "`";
$ind[50] = "-";
$ind[51] = "=";
$ind[52] = "?";

$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xml->load('pwDB.xml');
$finln = "";
#endregion

#region Create coded password
$pwlen = strlen($accstr);
for($cnter=1;$cnter<=$pwlen;$cnter++)
    {
        $a1 = substr($accstr,$cnter,1);
        for($cnter2=1;$cnter2<=52;$cnter2++)
            {
                if($a1==$ind[$cnter2])
                    {
                        $finln += $a[$cnter2];
                    }
            }
    }
#endregion

#region Send finln
$newpw = $xml->createElement($accn);
$newpw->appendChild($xml->createElement('password', $finln));
$xml->getElementsByTagName('cache')->item(0)->appendChild($newpw);
file_put_contents("pwDB.xml",$xml->saveXML());
print $finln;
#endregion
?>
```

Comment: What is the ultimate goal with this? What does "converting to more secure format" mean? What is the use case for this "secure format"?

Comment: For one thing: `substr` is `0` based; second: PHP arrays are also 0 based.

Comment: Why are you not using a salt with a standard hash type like SHA256, md5, etc.?

Comment: are you trying to come up with your own hashing "algorithm"?

Comment: @Adnan, in short, yes. The whole goal of this is to take a password and convert it to a different string into an XML document to be pulled up later, using the same key. I am new to PHP, which is also why I am having issues.

Comment: @prodigitalson, I've never heard of that before nor came across it. I'll look into it

Comment: @Aaron, why not use `mcrypt` for that matter. Here, this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/1289114/1105514
And what you said you're trying to do isn't hashing, it's encoding/decoding

Answer (score 1):

So typical password hashing is one way - if you need two way then youre talking about encryption which is different.

Normally for hashing youd do something like the following, though id urge not to take this verbatim but to research some on your own so oyu understand what youre doing and the concepts involved:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$xml->formatOutput = true;
$xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$xml->load('pwDB.xml');

$account = 'someuser';
$password = 'passw0rd';

// your salt can be a constant that you never change, or can be user specific
// if you make it user specific then you need to store it as well as the password
$salt = "1j0i90@$t%";

$hash = hash('sha256', $password . $salt);

$acct = $xml->createElement($account);
$pw = $xml->createElement('password', $salt);
$acct->appendChild($pw);

$xml->appendChild($acct);

file_put_contents("pwDB.xml",$xml->saveXML());
```

And then to compare credentials like for a login you would do:

```
    $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
    $xml->formatOutput = true;
    $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $xml->load('pwDB.xml');

    $account = 'someuser';
    $password = 'passw0rd';
    $salt = "1j0i90@$t%";

    $hash = hash('sha256', $password . $salt);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);

   // look up by account name - assuming these are unique
   $accountNodes = $xpath->query('//'.$account);
   if($accountNodes->length) {
      $accountNode = $accountNodes->item(0);
      $pwNodes = $xpath->query('//password', $accountNode);
      if($pwNodes->length) {
         $pwNode = $pwNodes->item(0);
         if($hash === (string) $pwNode) {
             // authentication OK!
         } 
      }
   }
```