# Password decryption not working after passing in URL

Tags: php, passwords, md5, encryption

I am using following [technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1289114/1360354) to encrypt/decrypt password:

```
$key = 'abcd';
$password = 'password';

$encrypted_password = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), $password, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));

$decrypted_password = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), base64_decode($encrypted_password), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "\0");
```

[Above code is working for me on same page](http://ideone.com/rRNj2)

But When I pass this encrypted password in URL to another webpage something like:

```
example.com/authenticate.php?pass=CuESFcvXHnQkZaY79WUL3U2aY9TROkjZFETk9Ur+iFY=
```

Then it is not decrypting it back in original form using same key and I am getting some garbage data as result.

I think it something like url **encoding/decoding** problem ?

Is there is any way to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you passing passwords in the URL to begin with? Can't you use sessions or opaque tokens?

Comment: This seems like an overkill. Any reason why you are not hashing the password instead? You should not even need a reversible algorithm for passwords. In fact, you should avoid trying to come up with your own password encrypting/hashing scheme...

Comment: because my mobile project is seperate and my web application is seperate project so thats why i am using this thing to log in the website from my mobile site.. and any other alternative solution to log in web project from mobile site..

Comment: But you do the password handling sever side, it should not matter where you access the site.

Comment: The *appropriate* way would be an Oauth or OpenID-like token-based login system, if simple cookies/sessions don't cut it. Of course, that's a lot more complex too...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`+` in the URL represents a space. If you want to pass arbitrary data in the URL, especially data that may contain *special characters*, [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode) it before putting it in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Your guessing is right:

you should urlencode the pass parameter before attaching it to the querystring.

```
urlencode($encrypted_password);
```

then urldecode before decrypting

```
urldecode($encrypted_password);
```

Happy coding!