# Wrong With Encrypt/Decrypt

Tags: php, encryption

I have copied source from the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289061/best-way-to-use-php-to-encrypt-and-decrypt)

and have created this two functions

```
function my_encrypt($string) {
    $key="1234";
    return base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), 
        $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));
}

function my_decrypt($string) {
    $key="1234";
    return rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), 
         base64_decode($string), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "\0");
}
```

And when I tried to encrypt and decrypt using the code shown below

```
 $string="445676467";
    echo $ecr=my_encrypt($string)."<br/>";
    echo my_decrypt($ecr);
```

The following output is produced

> 01pEoOCsp7oloZTDMAKF/cxgB0YQFScje6Z8GBXu8Tw=
>
> 445676467›HŽÇeVJMç>ÑÑBHc.–ãyeÇN–=“VSã

Wrong with this is that decrypt is not giving correct ouput which is `445676467`

but when I tried directly this

```
$key="1234";
    $string="2011";
    $encrypted= base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, 
        md5($key), $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))));

    $decypted= rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($key), 
        base64_decode($encrypted), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($key))), "\0");
    echo $encrypted."<br/>";
    echo $decypted;
```

this gives the correct answer

Comment: You need to `base64_decode` before decrypting the string.

Comment: i did not get it..will you create two function that i am trying to create and post in answer?

Comment: @RobertK Where do you see that it is not being base64 decoded? I see `base64_decode($string)` in both the working and non-working versions...

Comment: Your example isn't working because you're assigning `$ecr` to the return value of `my_encrypt($string)` *concatted with `<br />`*.

Comment: @Palladium: That probably ought to be an answer.  :)  I know i'd vote for it.

Comment: Why are you using `md5(md5($key))` as the IV? If anything, that just reduces the IV key space.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté anything that is directly calculated from the key would negate the whole function of the IV anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's funny but the reason is your syntex.

I used your code:

```
     $string="445676467";
//You echo & put value in the var at the same time?? smells like troubles.
        echo $ecr=my_encrypt($string)."<br/>"; 
        echo my_decrypt($ecr);
```

Result:

```
01pEoOCsp7oloZTDMAKF/cxgB0YQFScje6Z8GBXu8Tw=
445676467�H���eVJM�>��BHc.��ye�N�=�VS�
```

And tried:

```
 $string="445676467";
    $ecr=my_encrypt($string);
    echo $ecr;
    echo my_decrypt($ecr);
```

Result:

```
01pEoOCsp7oloZTDMAKF/cxgB0YQFScje6Z8GBXu8Tw=
445676467
```

Therefore , nothing wrong with your functions , just the usage.
First put the value in the variable and only then print it.