# php decryption failing from URL

Tags: php, encryption, mcrypt

I am using php decrypion to check that: an email address replying to a request is the same email address which was sent the request.

This is the code but at the bottom it simpy fails.

The url is simply:

```
blah.com/page?keyemail=fSHEk8KC17siklGHsj0HJA==
```

The code below also shows some tests i did to make sure the encrypt/decrypt were working ok... I echo'd down the code to see what was going on

```
$key="XiTo74UI09wwe4YeUmuvbL0E";

$iv = mcrypt_create_iv (mcrypt_get_block_size (MCRYPT_TripleDES, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), MCRYPT_DEV_RANDOM);

// Encrypting
function encrypt($string, $key) {
    $enc = "";
    global $iv;
    $enc=mcrypt_cbc (MCRYPT_TripleDES, $key, $string, MCRYPT_ENCRYPT, $iv);

  return base64_encode($enc);
}

// Decrypting
function decrypt($string, $key) {
    $dec = "";
    $string = trim(base64_decode($string));
    global $iv;
    $dec = mcrypt_cbc (MCRYPT_TripleDES, $key, $string, MCRYPT_DECRYPT, $iv);
  return $dec;
}

// test example
$email = 'me@me.com';

echo "email is $email<br /><br />";

$email_key = encrypt($email, $key);

echo "key is $email_key<br /><br />";

$email_key2 = decrypt($email_key, $key);

echo "decrypted is $email_key2<br /><br />";
// END test example, all is ok


// this is the code that fails
$to_de = $_GET[keyemail];

echo "keyemail again is $to_de<br /><br />";

$email_key3 = decrypt($to_de, $key);

echo $email_key3;
```

What is being returned when I echo $email_key3 is encoded somehow - it should be me@me.com

I'm probably missing something obvious but it's lost me!

Comment: Since you already know what email it should come from normally it is better to use hashes here instead however what is the var_dump of `$_GET['keyemail']` as it should be instead of `$_GET[keyemail]` since even though PHP to translate keyemail to a string it will also throw an E_NOTICE if I remember right.

Comment: Also what IS the return? Can you print that out for us too?

Answer (score 0):

You can't generate a new `IV` on each page - you must either store the `IV` from the encryption step in a file or database - or append it to the encrypted string. Generating a new IV on the next page will not allow you to decrypt the string.

Also, if possible I would pass a hash of an the email (plus a salt) - not an encrypted form.

Comment: When I do AES encryption/decryption I create a random IV everytime via: `$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);` so long as I have the same key and iv size I believe it should work (and does), unless that's something specific to that algorithm?

Comment: If a different IV works for both input and output - what's the point of the IV? Either it's not needed for your algorithm, or it needs to be identical.

Answer (score -1):

I've noticed that the encryption method you're using is adding a random salt. That means that encrypting the same string with the same key does not result in the same output.
Try using a non randomized KDF.
Try the answer of this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1289114/1745542

Comment: @meza: please learn how to use array indexes correctly: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar