# Exactly how do I use blowfish in PHP?

Tags: php, hash, passwords, blowfish, crypt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to use PHP to encrypt and decrypt passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289061/best-way-to-use-php-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-passwords)

I've been doing a lot with PHP recently and want to make my first login/registration system. As such I've been doing a lot of reading online to figure out the best method(s) for doing this. I've come across a couple of guides and I'm confused on a few instances and I'd like to be sure before I start down this road.

My question is how exactly do I use blowfish? I've read that crypt() will auto select blowfish if an appropriate salt is provided. If that is the case, What makes a salt blowfish appropriate?

Right now, I have a script that makes a salt out of the date and time, a random number, then hash that for the salt. Is that something I can use with blowfish or not?

Comment: For understanding you could have a look at the comments of this [example code](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/php/php.html#bcrypt), for using it, i would strongly recommend to use ircmaxell's excellent api. It is misleading that the second parameter of `crypt()` is called salt, actually it contains all crypt parameters including the salt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php

If you scroll down about 1/3, you should see the heading: `Example #3 Using crypt() with different hash types`. Hopefully this will help! and your salt should be fine!

Comment: I have seen that but I'm still confused. Do I just tack $2a$07$ to the front of my salt (and another $ to the end) to make it use blowfish? Also, what is the 07 in that example, the number of rounds?

Comment: Yes exactly, with the 07, the higher number, the more rounds and the longer it takes

Answer (score 12):

In short: don't build it yourself. Use a library.

In PHP 5.5, there will be a new API available to make this process easier on you. Here's the [RFC for it](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/password_hash).

I've also created a backwards-compatibility library for it here: [password-compat](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat):

```
$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

And then to verify:

```
if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
    /* Valid */
} else {
    /* Invalid */
}
```

And if you want another library, check out [phpass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/)

In short, don't do it yourself. There's no need. Just import the library and be done with it...

Comment: I've read that, and will probably use that in the long run, but I like to understand how to do things myself. Thanks for the tip, but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @sharf: look at what the libraries do (the compat one should be pretty easy to read). That should give you insight on how it all works...

Comment: That still doesn't answer my question.

Comment: This is not exactly what the OP asks, but this is the answer the OP needs

Comment: @BenDuffin: You actually just proved my point with your comment. `crypt()` can do bcrypt. But it is easy to screw up. It is easy to wind up in a situation where you kill security. Which is why I did not recommend actually using it directly, but using a library. Because cryptography is hard, and you shouldn't do it yourself if you have an alternative. And there are alternatives.