# Encrypt & Decrypt String - PHP

Tags: php, encryption

I have `file1.php` & `file2.php`, in `file1.php` have some links, example :

```
<a href="http://google.com/">Open google site</a>
<a href="http://facebook.com/">Open facebook site</a>
```

I try to make safelink on `file1.php`, I'm use this function to encrypt

```
function enc_safelink($url_target){
    $key = '1q2w3e4r5t'; 
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(
    mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC),
    MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM
    );

    $encrypted = base64_encode(
        $iv .
        mcrypt_encrypt(
            MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
            hash('sha256', $key, true),
            $url_target,
            MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
            $iv
        )
    );
    return $encrypted;
}
```

So all link on `file1.php` will be like this :

```
<a href="file2.php?link=D6/thGZQ3MpUf6ePqqDBrXdQC3rAVQHMHGm9KOn6GVjB3CNyDqljwt7DIwkWU6HV">Open google site</a>
<a href="file2.php?link=HYOyBzxnpd1MrzN4YMF1qpWSg4KMlE1mz2HTxOl+ZGdS3zUSQymoMIPoBMVu3Mpm">Open facebook site</a>
```

In `file2.php` I want to show a link and get permalink from parameter

```
 <?php
  function dnc_safelink($params_code){
    $key = '1q2w3e4r5t';
    $data = base64_decode($params_code);
    $iv = substr($data, 0, mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC));

    $decrypted = rtrim(
       mcrypt_decrypt(
       MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
       hash('sha256', $key, true),
       substr($data, mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC)),
       MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
       $iv
    ),
    "\0"
    );
    return $decrypted;
  }
  if ( isset($_GET["link"]) ) :
    $dnc_url = dnc_safelink($_GET['link']);
    echo '<div style="text-align:center" id="aDivSafeLink"><a href="'.$dnc_url.'">Download Here</a></div>';
  endif;
 ?>
```

But the output like this :

```
<a href="�uJ�`*���_����gyܥ�w�W�X�#">Download Here</a>
```

I'm sure, I have tested on the same page the encrypt & decrypt function works perfectly. How can I use encryption & decryption a string with different page or different site?

Source of function : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1289114

Comment: What's stopping you from just using https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption?

Comment: Are you sure that `$params_code` is the full link during decryption? Perhaps some characters were lost. Hint: url-safe base64

Comment: @ArtjomB. oh I know, Thanks for the hint ;)

Comment: If you have solved the question, you should write your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use encryption & decryption a string with different page or different site?

If you find yourself encrypting URL parameters, you've made a mistake.

#### What People Want To Do Here

[image: Some encryption function is used to deterministically retrieve the ID]

#### What People Should Do Instead

[image: Use a separate column]

---

Instead of encryption, use `random_bytes()` in conjunction with either `bin2hex()` or `base64_encode()`. If you use Base64, make the number of bytes you generate an even multiple of 3 (e.g. `random_bytes(24)` for a 32-character string).

You can also use [URL-safe base64](https://github.com/paragonie/constant_time_encoding) like so:

```
<?php
use ParagonIE\ConstantTime\Base64UrlSafe;

$token = Base64UrlSafe::encode(random_bytes(24));
```

But encryption is simply [the wrong tool for the job](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php).