# How to make Expiring/Signed video urls

Tags: php

I have cpanel and I am looking to setup video streams for my clients.

I need to setup one time use url like suggested in below thread

[How to make Expiring/Signed video embed urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41068432/how-to-make-expiring-signed-video-embed-urls?answertab=active#tab-top)

I have tried exactly the same what was suggested from it, but I can't even play a simple .mp4 file through the file path.

**My reference Code:**

**libraries/VideoSignature.php**

```
<?php

/*
 * This class allows you to:
 * - Encrypt filepaths and expiration dates into signatures
 * - Decrypt signatures into filepaths and expiration dates
 *
 *
 * Note: String encryption functions were found here:
 * http://stackoverflow.com/a/1289114/1913729
 */

class VideoSignature
{
    // Time before a URL expires, in seconds
    private $expires = 10;
    // Key used to sign your URLs
    private $encryption_key = 'soMeStr0ngP455W0rD!!';
    // Public URL used to serve the content
    private $proxy_url = '/getVideo.php';

    // Encrypts a string
    private function encryptStr($str){
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(
            mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC),
            MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM
        );

        $encrypted = base64_encode(
            $iv .
            mcrypt_encrypt(
                MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
                hash('sha256', $this->encryption_key, true),
                $str,
                MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
                $iv
            )
        );

        return $encrypted;
    }

    // Decrypts a String
    private function decryptStr($str){
        $data = base64_decode($str);
        $iv = substr($data, 0, mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC));

        $decrypted = rtrim(
            mcrypt_decrypt(
                MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
                hash('sha256', $this->encryption_key, true),
                substr($data, mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC)),
                MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
                $iv
            ),
            "\0"
        );

        return $decrypted;
    }

    // Returns a temporary URL
    public function getSignedURL($filepath){
        $data = json_encode(
                array(
                    "filepath" => $filepath,
                    "expires" => time() + $this->expires
                )
            );

        $signature = $this->encryptStr($data);

        return $this->proxy_url . "?s=" . urlencode($signature);
    }

    // Returns a filepath from a signature if it did not expire
    public function getFilepath($signature){
        $data = json_decode( $this->decryptStr($signature), true);

        if($data !== null && $data['expires'] > time() && file_exists($data['filepath'])){
            return $data['filepath'];
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**libraries/VideoStream.php**

```
<?php

/*
 * This class was found here:
 * http://stackoverflow.com/a/39897793/1913729
 *
 * It allows you to stream video without giving the real file URL
 */

class VideoStream
{
    private $path = "";
    private $stream = "";
    private $buffer = 102400;
    private $start  = -1;
    private $end    = -1;
    private $size   = 0;

    function __construct($filePath) 
    {
        $this->path = $filePath;
    }

    /**
     * Open stream
     */
    private function open()
    {
        if (!($this->stream = fopen($this->path, 'rb'))) {
            die('Could not open stream for reading');
        }

    }

    /**
     * Set proper header to serve the video content
     */
    private function setHeader()
    {
        ob_get_clean();
        header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
        header("Cache-Control: max-age=2592000, public");
        header("Expires: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+2592000) . ' GMT');
        header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', @filemtime($this->path)) . ' GMT' );
        $this->start = 0;
        $this->size  = filesize($this->path);
        $this->end   = $this->size - 1;
        header("Accept-Ranges: 0-".$this->end);

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {

            $c_start = $this->start;
            $c_end = $this->end;

            list(, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
            if (strpos($range, ',') !== false) {
                header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
                header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/$this->size");
                exit;
            }
            if ($range == '-') {
                $c_start = $this->size - substr($range, 1);
            }else{
                $range = explode('-', $range);
                $c_start = $range[0];

                $c_end = (isset($range[1]) && is_numeric($range[1])) ? $range[1] : $c_end;
            }
            $c_end = ($c_end > $this->end) ? $this->end : $c_end;
            if ($c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $this->size - 1 || $c_end >= $this->size) {
                header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
                header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/$this->size");
                exit;
            }
            $this->start = $c_start;
            $this->end = $c_end;
            $length = $this->end - $this->start + 1;
            fseek($this->stream, $this->start);
            header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
            header("Content-Length: ".$length);
            header("Content-Range: bytes $this->start-$this->end/".$this->size);
        }
        else
        {
            header("Content-Length: ".$this->size);
        }  

    }

    /**
     * close curretly opened stream
     */
    private function end()
    {
        fclose($this->stream);
        exit;
    }

    /**
     * perform the streaming of calculated range
     */
    private function stream()
    {
        $i = $this->start;
        set_time_limit(0);
        while(!feof($this->stream) && $i <= $this->end) {
            $bytesToRead = $this->buffer;
            if(($i+$bytesToRead) > $this->end) {
                $bytesToRead = $this->end - $i + 1;
            }
            $data = fread($this->stream, $bytesToRead);
            echo $data;
            flush();
            $i += $bytesToRead;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Start streaming video content
     */
    function start()
    {
        $this->open();
        $this->setHeader();
        $this->stream();
        $this->end();
    }
}
```

**index.php**

```
// Load the signature helper functions
include "libraries/VideoSignature.php";
$vs = new VideoSignature();

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Check out my video!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- /!\ Here, you need to insert a path to your video,
         relative to the getVideo.php file, not an actual URL! -->
    <video src="<?=$vs->getSignedURL("server/path/to/video.mp4");?>"></video>
</body>
</html>
```

**getVideo.php**

```
<?php

// Load the signature helper functions
include "libraries/VideoSignature.php";
$vs = new VideoSignature();
// Load the video streaming functions
include "libraries/VideoStream.php";


if(isset($_REQUEST['s']) && $filepath = $vs->getFilepath($_REQUEST['s'])){
    $stream = new VideoStream($filepath);
    $stream->start();
} else {
    header("HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden");
    echo "This URL has expired.";
}
```

I have already checked about the file permissions and it works fine with hotlink "www.mydomain/path/test.mp4"

But when I use the reference like getSignedURL("play/tester/test.mp4");?>"> as suggested, the video won't start and the console has an error 'file not found 404 error'.

I need someone who can help explain to me how to get the video url to be player when I access index.php.

The only thing I am looking to add a direct URL and stream along with signature.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - You need to show us your file structure and your code.

Comment: I have added my actual requirement, any help?

Comment: Can anyone please help me on this request.